# Fibonacci Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi everbody I need to change my F# code to Haskell code  but I am so new in Haskell and I can not this My code simply read data from keyboard if data not an integer return an error message then calculate the n fibonacci number then writes to a list after that writes the list into a txt file Here is my code

```
open System
let rec fib n = 
    match n with
    |0->0
    |1->1
    |2->1
    |n->fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);;

let printFibonacci list = 
    for i=0 to (List.length list)-1 do
        printf "%d " (list.Item(i));;

let writeToFile list = 
    let file = System.IO.File.Create("C:\out2.txt")
    let mutable s =""
    let writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file)
    try
        for i=0 to (List.length list)-1 do
        s <- list.Item(i).ToString()
        writer.Write(s+" ")

    finally
        writer.Close()
        file.Dispose()
        printfn "Writed To File"


let mutable control = true
let mutable num = 0
while control do 
    try
    printfn "Enter a Number:" 

    num <- Convert.ToInt32(stdin.ReadLine()) 
    let listFibonacci = [for i in 0 .. num-1->fib(i)]
    printFibonacci(listFibonacci)
    printfn "\n%A"(listFibonacci)
    writeToFile(listFibonacci)
    control<-false
    with
        | :? System.FormatException->printfn "Number Format Exception";

Console.ReadKey true|>ignore
```

Comment: This is covered pretty well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105765/generating-fibonacci-numbers-in-haskell

Comment: Google will give you the Haskell wiki page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence that covers this in detail.

Answer (score 15):

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

main = do putStrLn "Enter a number:"
          num <- readLn
          fibs = map fib [0..n]
          mapM' print fibs
```

However since haskell is lazy there is a clever way to define the list of all fibonacci numbers. And since you want a prefix of that list, it's more natural to use this definition (also more efficient):

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

main = do putStrLn "Enter a number:"
          num <- readLn
          mapM' print (take n fibs)
```

Edit: To write to a file instead of stdout replace `print` with `(\num -> appendFile "filename" (show num))` or `(appendFile "filename" . show)`.

Answer (score 2):

That is basically the most common implementation of the sequence itself:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

If you want the number from keyboard:

```
main :: IO ()
main = catch doFib handle
   where doFib = do
            num <- readLn
            putStrLn $ "Fib of " ++ show num ++ " = " ++ (show . fib $ num)
         handle _ -> putStrLn "Malformed input!"
```

Done!

Comment: Are you really recommending an algorithm with a complexity of O(2^n)? It is going to be horribly slow for anything other than small values of n.

Comment: Not recommending! Just saying it's the most basic, and (most importantly here, as he is new to haskell!) easiest implementation.

Comment: @Yacoby: that's an exact translation of OP's algorithm implemented in F#, so it's a translation, not a recommendation.

Comment: @LukeN , using your code, I got error "error: parse error on input `->'", Im new to FP, sorry.