# Fibonacci sequence in haskell returning all the values

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I need help for my assignment using haskell which return a list up to the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence.

like

```
Main> fib 5
[0,1,1,2,3,5]
Main> fib 15
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610]
```

I understand this

```
fib::Int->Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

but I don't know how to produce list that containing all the value up to the nth number.

Thank you

Comment: print n over the function.

Comment: The very simple, but performance-wise idiotic way would be to simply [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map) `fib` over `[1..n]`. For example: `fibs n = map fib [1..n]`.

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu How would I do it? I'm a very beginner, it would be very helpful if you can give me an example

Comment: @gspr thank you it works, but is there a way to include that(fibs n= map fib[1..n]) into fib function?

Comment: @SahyunKim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803920/fibonacci-numbers-in-haskell

Comment: You can find some nice examples in [fibonacci](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence). Personally I fell in love with the `unfoldr` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few cool ways to do it, first the simplest

```
fib::Int->Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
fibList n = map fib [1..n]
```

or we can merge this into one

```
fib::Int->[Int]
fib 0 = [0]
fib 1 = [1, 0]
fib n = (head (fib (n-1)) + head (fib (n-2))) : fib (n-1)
```

So here we're just combining the list building with the recursion. Now we take a step towards the crazy

```
fib n = take n fiblist
  where fiblist = 0:1:(zipWith (+) fiblist (tail fiblist))
```

Here `fiblist` is an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers. All we're doing is grabbing the appropriate amount. This is possible because Haskell is "lazy". If you're new to Haskell, just smile and nod.

Lastly, for kicks and giggles

```
fib = flip take . fix $ \f -> 0 : 1 : (zipWith (+) f (tail f))
```

This is the same of above except point-free and with a fixed point instead of recursion.

Again if you're new to haskell, the first 2 are a little easier to grok, come back to the last 2 in a few weeks :)

Comment: Thank you, it's wonderful answer!