# Haskell: Code running too slow

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, motzkin-numbers

I have a code which computes a Motzkin number as:

```
module Main where

    -- Program execution begins here
    main :: IO ()
    main = interact (unlines . (map show) . map wave . (map read) . words)

    -- Compute Motzkin number
    wave :: Integer -> Integer
    wave 0 = 1
    wave 1 = 1
    wave n = ((3 * n - 3) * wave (n - 2) + (2 * n + 1) * wave (n - 1)) `div` (n + 2)
```

But the output for even a simple number as `30` takes a while to return.

Any optimization ideas??

Comment: memoization might help.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization

Answer (score 10):

There is a standard trick for computing the Fibonacci numbers that can easily be adapted to your problem. The naive definition for Fibonacci numbers is:

```
fibFunction :: Int -> Integer
fibFunction 0 = 1
fibFunction 1 = 1
fibFunction n = fibFunction (n-2) + fibFunction (n-1)
```

However, this is very costly: since all the leaves of the recursion are `1`, if `fib x = y`, then we must perform `y` recursive calls! Since the Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, this is a bad state of affairs to be in. But with dynamic programming, we can share the computations needed in the two recursive calls. The pleasing one-liner for this looks like this:

```
fibList :: [Integer]
fibList = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibList (tail fibList)
```

This may look a bit puzzling at first; here the `fibList` argument to `zipWith` serves as the recursion on two indices ago, while the `tail fibList` argument serves as the recursion on one index ago, which gives us both the `fib (n-2)` and `fib (n-1)` values. The two `1`s at the beginning are of course the base cases. There are [other good questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1105765/791604) that explain this technique in further detail, and you should study this code and those answers until you feel you understand how it works and why it is very fast.

If necessary, one can recover the `Int -> Integer` type signature from this using `(!!)`.

Let's try to apply this technique to your function. As with computing Fibonacci numbers, you need the previous and second-to-last values; and additionally need the current index. That can be done by including `[2..]` in the call to `zipWith`. Here's how it would look:

```
waves :: [Integer]
waves = 1 : 1 : zipWith3 thisWave [2..] waves (tail waves) where
    thisWave n back2 back1 = ((3 * n - 3) * back2 + (2 * n + 1) * back1) `div` (n + 2)
```

As before, one can recover the function version with `(!!)` or `genericIndex` (if one really needs `Integer` indices). We can confirm that it computes the same function (but faster, and using less memory) in ghci:

```
> :set +s
> map wave [0..30]
[1,1,2,4,9,21,51,127,323,835,2188,5798,15511,41835,113634,310572,853467,2356779,6536382,18199284,50852019,142547559,400763223,1129760415,3192727797,9043402501,25669818476,73007772802,208023278209,593742784829,1697385471211]
(6.00 secs, 3,334,097,776 bytes)
> take 31 waves
[1,1,2,4,9,21,51,127,323,835,2188,5798,15511,41835,113634,310572,853467,2356779,6536382,18199284,50852019,142547559,400763223,1129760415,3192727797,9043402501,25669818476,73007772802,208023278209,593742784829,1697385471211]
(0.00 secs, 300,696 bytes)
```

Answer (score 6):

With n=30, you need to compute `wave 29` and `wave 28`, which, in turn, needs to compute `wave 28`, `wave 27` twice and `wave 26` and so forth, this quickly goes in the billions.

You can employ the same trick that is used in computation of the fibonacci numbers:

```
wave 0 = 1
wave 1 = 1
wave n = helper 1 1 2
    where
       helper x y k | k <n      = helper y z (k+1)
                    | otherwise = z
                    where z = ((3*k-3) * x + (2*k+1) * y) `div` (k+2)
```

This runs in linear time, and the helper has, for every `k` the values for  `wave (k-2)` and `wave (k-1)` ready.

Comment: I think you are missing parenthesis in the last line before the div (div should apply to the sum of the terms).

Answer (score 1):

here is a memoized version

```
wave = ((1:1:map waveCalc [2..]) !!)
    where waveCalc n = ( (2*n+1)*wave (n-1) + (3*n-3)*wave (n-2) ) `div` (n+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses. Based on my understanding of `Memoization`, I have re-written the code as:

```
mwave :: Int -> Int
mwave = (map wave [0..] !!)
  where wave 0 = 1
        wave 1 = 1
        wave n = ((3 * n - 3) * mwave (n - 2) + (2 * n + 1) * mwave (n - 1)) `div` (n + 2)

digits :: Int -> Int
digits n = (mwave n) `mod` 10^(100::Int)
```

Any thoughts on how to **output the answer modulo 10^100?**

Comment: You will need to use the `Integer` type for your `mwave` function. `Int` does not support 100-digit numbers.

Comment: you wanted `Integer`; `Int` is no good here (try `mwave !! 43`).  see https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Integer+-%3E+a.

Comment: @WillNess When I change the signature of `mwave`, it gives and error: `Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' with actual type Int'`

Comment: yes, `!!` is the culprit, its type is: .... (try `Prelude> :t (!!)`) . And the type of `genericIndex` is: .... . Have you tried the link I provided above?

Comment: @WillNess, I cannot use external packages other than the ones in `Prelude`. Can you suggest an alternative?? Thanks.

Comment: in that case, give it the big type and sprinkle the `fromIntegral`s throughout your code for good measure. I.e. instead of `a !! n` write `a !! (fromIntegral n)`. Or better, give it the `Int -> Integer` signature and write `(3 * fromIntegral n - 3) * mwave (n - 2) ...`. `n` will be `Int` (and `!!` expects `Int` as its 2nd arg), but the result of `mwave n` will be `Integer`, hence `fromIntegral n` will be `Integer` and calculation will typecheck.