# Understanding recursive fibonacci function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

Although this thread were available, I wasn't allowed to ask my question under the answers (due to reputation points) therefore I had to create a new question for that regard. (I am just new in stackoverflow :)

I didn't clearly understand one point regarding how following fibs function works

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

In this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105765/generating-fibonacci-numbers-in-haskell/57188964#57188964?newreg=a13c92bfe66b4f65b1e8570d83b7522d)

nichijou has step by step explained below the thread here I quoted from nichijou:

> at first, with fibs and tail fibs, we can get the 3rd:
>
> ```
> fibs                        : [1, 1, ?
> tail fibs                   : [1, ?
> zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs): [2, ?
> ```
>
> now, we know the 3rd is 2, we can get the 4th:
>
> ```
> fibs                        : [1, 1, 2, ?
> tail fibs                   : [1, 2, ?
> zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs): [2, 3, ?
> ```
>
> now the 5th:
>
> ```
> fibs                        : [1, 1, 2, 3, ?
> tail fibs                   : [1, 2, 3, ?
> zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs): [2, 3, 5, ?
> ```
>
> and so on ..

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Here my question is, after the second step how did we get rid of the duplicates in the list? I was expecting to see the second step should generate a list as

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

same goes in the next step and so on...

Comment: We did not generate duplicates. Where do you see duplicates here?

Comment: Asking a new question is the right thing to do. You should avoid seeing the list as developing in "steps". When we refer to `fibs` in that definition, we really mean the whole list. The accepted answer is better at explaining this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no duplicates in running code, it works completely fine but I was wondering how come there is no duplicates when I iterate the recursion myself. Now the answer clarified my mind, understood the process better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's write this out with some more labels:

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1 : 1 : sumft
 where sumft = zipWith (+) fibs tfi
       tfi = tail fibs
```

Then, the “starting step” is

```
           ╭── tfi ───────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, ?, ?, ...
              ╰── sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, ?, ?, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, ?, ?, ?,
```

Now, as the computation marches on, the runtime don't *move anything* or whatever, it merely tries to fill in `?` signs with concrete values. Remember, everything in Haskell is immutable; when I write `?` I just mean I don't know yet what the value there is, but in principle it's already predetermined.

In this case, the runtime knows that the first `?` in `fibs` comes from the head of `sumft`, whose exact value is known by now:

```
           ╭─── tfi ──────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, 2, ?, ...
              ╰─◀ sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, ?, ?, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, ?, ?, ?,
```

Now, this `2` is also known in `tfi`:

```
           ╭──▶ tfi ──────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, 2, ?, ...
              ╰── sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, 2, ?, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, ?, ?, ?,
```

...and thus we can perform the next addition:

```
           ╭─── tfi ──────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, 2, ?, ...
              ╰── sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, 2, ?, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, 3, ?, ?,
```

So, another number, i.e. another element of `sumft` that, being part of `fibs`, can also be used there. But it still occurs at the same place *relative to the head of `sumft`* – i.e. after the `2`.

```
           ╭─── tfi ──────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, 2, 3, ...
              ╰─◀ sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, 2, ?, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, 3, ?, ?,
```

That gets again used in `tfi`

```
           ╭──▶ tfi ──────┈┄··
fibs : [1, 1, 2, 3, ...
              ╰── sumft ──┈┄··
tfi  : [1, 2, 3, ?, ... 
sumft: [2, 3, ?, ?,
```

...and so on and so on.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation; very well understood. :)

Comment: You forgot to use U+254c in your fadeout :)

Comment: Always providing excellent answers. Superb actually. Very nice answer here!