# Recursive calls for fibonacci sequence

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

For finding Fibonacci numbers recursively the relation is f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2).
How many times is f(n-i) called (in terms of n and i) for recursive function of f(n) ?

I understand that while tracing the recursive calls a binary tree is made. However there does not appear to be any fixed pattern for determining number of recursive calls to f(n-i).Any advice ?

For example, in finding f(5),

```
f(5)=f(4)+f(3)  
f(5)=f(3)+f(2)+f(2)+f(1)  
f(5)=f(2)+f(1)+f(1)+f(0)+f(1)+f(0)+f(1)  
f(5)=f(1)+f(0)+f(1)+f(1)+f(0)+f(1)+f(0)+f(1)
```

Here number of calls to f(5)-1,f(4)-1,f(3)-2,f(2)-3,f(1)-5,f(0)-3.

Thanks.

Comment: See [Number of calls for nth Fibonacci number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738923/number-of-calls-for-nth-fibonacci-number)

Comment: Thanks but that discussion is on the total number of calls made to for finding f(n). However, I want to know about the calls made to one specific f(n-i) in computation of f(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3 should look familiar, because ignoring the last number it is the Fibonacci sequence again.

Let *c(x)* be the number of times *fib(x)* is called in the computation of *fib(n)*.

- *c(x) = 0* for all *x > n*, since *fib(x)* is never called.
- *c(n) = 1*, as *fib(n)* is called exactly once.
- *c(x) = c(x + 1) + c(x + 2)* for all *0 < x < n*, as *fib(x)* is called from *fib(x + 1)* and *fib(x + 2)*.
- *c(0)* = *c(2)*, a special case, since *fib(0)* is called from *fib(2)* but not *fib(1)*.

So the sequence *c(n), c(n-1), ..., c(2), c(1)* is the Fibonacci sequence and *c(0)* is equal to *c(2)*.

In terms of *i* and *n*,

- *fib(n - i)* is called *fib(i + 1)* times for *0 ≤ i < n*
- *fib(n - n) = fib(0)* is called *fib(n - 1)* times.