# Worst case running time of this algorithm (how to justify)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, analysis

I have an algorithm i'm trying to implement. I've been asked to determine a function that describes its worst case running time. As input, it takes an array of some length (lets call it n). Then what it does is as follows:

```
if (n==0){ return 0;}
else if(n==1){return A[0];}
else{
     return f(n-1)+f(n-2)
}
```

Sorry if I'm a tad sparse on the implementation details, but in a sense, its rather similar to something like the fibbanoci sequence. I'm thinking the worst case running time of this algorithm is t(n)=2^n, because if n is large, it will decompose into 2 separate calculations, which in turn will split into 2 more and so on. I'm just not sure how to formally justify this

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326634/complexity-for-recursive-functions-time-and-space

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm sorta looking for a bit of an explanation of how exactly you determine these things. I've looked around, but people just seem to start throwing notation and answers around without a good explanation. I'm kinda new to this whole thing

Comment: There's no quick answer. You need to understand recurrence relations in the context of algorithmic complexity in order to prove your result. The accepted answer on the question I linked links to a page that explains it: http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html (See heading "The Recurrence Relation" and beyond)

Comment: With what you show from the code, there is no worst case, you only use A[0] whatever the value of n ... show us more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first get a recursion for the running time.

```
T(0) = T(1) = 1
```

since both just return a number (one is an array-lookup, but that's constant time too). And for `n > 1` we have

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1
```

since you evaluate `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)` and add the two results. That's almost the same recurrence as the Fibonacci sequence itself, `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`, and the result is closely related.

```
 n | T(n) | F(n)
----------------
 0 |   1  |   0
 1 |   1  |   1
 2 |   3  |   1
 3 |   5  |   2
 4 |   9  |   3
 5 |  15  |   5
 6 |  25  |   8
 7 |  41  |  13
 8 |  67  |  21
 9 | 109  |  34
10 | 177  |  55
11 | 287  |  89
```

If you look at the values, you see that

```
T(n) = F(n+2) + F(n-1) - 1
```

and can prove that with induction, if you need to.

Since the terms of the Fibonacci sequence are given by `F(n) = (φ^n - (1-φ)^n)/√5`, where `φ = (1 + √5)/2`, you see that the complexity of your `f` is also `Θ(φ^n)`, like that of the Fibonacci sequence. That's better than `Θ(2^n)`, but still exponential, so calculation using this way is only feasible for small `n`.

Comment: if `A[0] == 1` isn't the OP definition *exactly* the definition of Fibonacci sequence? Fibonacci calculation too adds the two sub-cases. So why there should be _any_ difference?

Comment: The exact code in the last return is slightly different, but is of the same level of complexity. Its just a comparison with some other array element.

Comment: @WillNess Whatever `A[0]` is, the sequence will be `A[0]*F(n)`, so the complexity of computing it the naive way is exactly that of computing `F(n)` the naive way. The cost of computing `F(n)` the naive way is usually called `nfib(n)`, which can be expressed like above by Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel; I've edited to clarify the sentence, with apologies for intrusion. :)

Comment: @WillNess Yeah, I guess that's clearer for people not being able to read my mind, thanks.