# Big-O and Omega Notations

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

I was reading this question [Big-O notation's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645757/big-o-notations-definition).
But I have less than 50 reputation to comment, so I hope someone help me.

My question is about this sentence:

> There are many algorithms for which there is no single function g such that the complexity is both O(g) and Ω(g). For instance, insertion sort has a Big-O lower bound of O(n²) (meaning you can't find anything smaller than n²) and an Ω upper bound of Ω(n).

for large n the O(n²) is an upper bound and Ω(n) is a lower bound, or maybe I have misunderstood?
could someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> has a Big-O lower bound of O(n²)

I don't really agree with the confusing way this was phrased (since big-O is itself an upper bound), but what I'm reading here is the following:

Big-O is an upper bound.

That is to say, `f(n) ϵ O(g(n))` is true if `|f(n)| <= k|g(n)|` as `n` tends to infinity ([by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

So let's say we have a function `f(n) = n2` (which is, if we ignore constant factors, the worst-case for insertion sort). We can say `n2 ϵ O(n2)`, but we can also say `n2 ϵ O(n3)` or `n2 ϵ O(n4)` or `n2 ϵ O(n5)` or ....

So the smallest `g(n)` we can find is `n2`.

---

But the answer you linked to is, as a whole, incorrect - insertion sort itself does not have upper or lower bounds, but rather it has best, average and worst cases, which have upper and lower bounds.

See the answer I posted there.

Comment: could you tell me, what is the omega notation for Fibonacci algorithm; and how to calculate it?

Comment: @O-BL See [Exponential lower bound for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571433/exponential-lower-bound-for-fibonacci-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

> maybe I have misunderstood?

No, you are right.

In general, the Big-O is for the upper bound and big-Ω for the lower bound.

For Insertion sort the worst case scenario, the upper bound is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Ω(n) is a lower bound.

<sub>It seems like you find a mistake in the other answer.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a mistake, but it is a confusing way to phrase it. See the answer I posted here and there.