# Time complexity of a recursive fibonnaci program

Tags: c, algorithm, math, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Hi,
I found out a inductive proof yesterday for the time complexity of a recursive Fibonacci program.The proof first claimed that the complexity is exponential(and later goes on to prove it by induction) by saying that:

> There exists a "r" such that f(n) >=
> r^n for all r>=1 and n>=1.
>
> Then it chooses r to be equal to 1+sqrt(5)/2 such that it satisfies the equation r^2 = r + 1.
>
> (It later justifies it's choice for r).
>
> And then it says that now the statement becomes f(n) >= r^(n-2).

I didn't understand this part how does it become r^(n-2) from r^n.Can someone please help me with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel says, `r` is greater than 1 so `r^n` is greater than `r^(n-1)` which is greater than `r^(n-2)` etc...

So you have indeed: `f(n) >= r^n >= r^(n-1) >= r^(n-2)`

Answer (score 2):

- `f(n) >= r^n`
- `r * r * f(n) >= r^n` (since `r > 1`)
- `f(n) >= r^(n-2)`

I don't see how this relates to time complexity, though..? It sounds more like a discussion leading up to Binet's formula.

Comment: It shows that `f(n)` is `Ω(r^n)` by showing that `f(n) >= r^n` for some _r_ and sufficiently large _n_.

Comment: @hammer I see, it just seems like a funny approach. In my mind, the natural argument is this: `f(n) = 2*f(n-2)` is trivially exponential (given `f(1) = 1`) since it doubles every two steps, and `f(n-1) + f(n-2) > 2*f(n-2)` since `f` increases monotonically, hence `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` is also exponential. Isn't that simpler? :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a somewhat convoluted approach.