# Proving this recursive Fibonacci implementation runs in time O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, fibonacci, proof

I'm having difficulty proving that the 'bad' version of fibonacci is O(2^n).
Ie.
Given the function

```
int fib(int x)
{
  if ( x == 1 || x == 2 )
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return ( f( x - 1 ) + f( x - 2) );
  }
}
```

Can I get help for the proof of this being O(2^n).

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7547133/1968462

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a duplicate of the linked one.  The linked one asks specifically to see where a particular line of reasoning breaks down, while this is a more general question about how to prove the upper bound is O(2^n) with no starting assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

Let's start off by writing a recurrence relation for the runtime:

> T(1) = 1
>
> T(2) = 1
>
> T(n+2) = T(n) + T(n + 1) + 1

Now, let's take a guess that

> T(n) ≤ 2<sup>n</sup>

If we try to prove this by induction, the base cases check out:

> T(1) = 1 ≤ 2 = 2<sup>1</sup>
>
> T(2) = 1 ≤ 4 = 2<sup>2</sup>

Then, in the inductive step, we see this:

> T(n + 2) = T(n) + T(n + 1) + 1
>
> ≤ 2<sup>n</sup> + 2<sup>n+1</sup> + 1
>
> < 2<sup>n+1</sup> + 2<sup>n+1</sup>
>
> = 2<sup>n+2</sup>

Therefore, by induction, we can conclude that T(n) ≤ 2<sup>n</sup> for any n, and therefore T(n) = O(2<sup>n</sup>).

With a more precise analysis, you can prove that T(n) = 2F<sub>n</sub> - 1, where F<sub>n</sub> is the nth Fibonacci number.  This proves, more accurately, that T(n) = Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>), where φ is the Golden Ratio, which is approximately 1.61.  Note that φ<sup>n</sup> = o(2<sup>n</sup>) (using little-o notation), so this is a much better bound.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try manually doing a few test cases like `f(5)` and take note of how many times the method `f()` is called.

A fat hint would be to notice that every time the method `f()` is called (except for x is 1 or 2), `f()` is called twice. Each of those call `f()` two more times each, and so on...

Comment: While this gives a good intuition, that really isn't a proof.

Comment: @templatetypedef -- I know, I didn't think it would be good to just give him a straight answer (it felt too much like something from a basic pset)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a pretty simple proof that the total number of calls to the `f` is going to be `2Fib(n)-1`, where `Fib(n)` is the n'th Fibonacci number.  It goes like this:

1. The set of calls to `f` form a binary tree, where each call is either a leaf (for x=1 or x=2) or else the call spawns two child calls (for x>2).
2. Each leaf contributes exactly 1 to the total returned by the original call, therefore there are `Fib(n)` total leaves.
3. The total number of internal nodes in any binary tree is equal to `L-1`, where `L` is the number of leaves, so the total number of nodes in this tree is `2L-1`.

This shows that the running time (measured in terms of total calls to `f`) is

```
T(n)=2Fib(n)-1=O(Fib(n))
```

and since `Fib(n)=Θ(φ^n)`, where `φ` is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)

```
Φ=(1+sqrt{5})/2 = 1.618...
```

this proves that `T(n) = Θ(1.618...^n) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Recursion Tree Method :

```
                                             T(n)                         
                                       ↙            ↘
                                   n-1              n – 2                                 
                               ↙      ↘             ↙      ↘
                           N – 2      n – 3      n – 3       n - 4
```

Each tree level is considered as a call for fib(x - 1) fib(x - 2)  if you complete the recursion tree on this manner you will stop when x = 1 or x = 2 (base case) .... this tree shows only three levels of the recursion tree . To solve this tree you need these important informations : 1- height of the tree. 2-how much work is done at each level .
The height of this tree is 2^n and the work at each level is O(1) then the Order of this recurrence is Height * Work at each level = 2^n * 1 = O(2^n)

Comment: Note that the tree isn't a perfect binary tree.  The branch for n - 2 drops off twice as early as the branch for n - 1.  That's why this only works out to an upper bound rather than a tight bound.

Comment: @templatetypedef I know ... But proving any recurrence with recursion tree is the simplest way