# analysis of fibonacci algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am reading an analysis of a fibanocci number program, shown below. It is mentioned that this implementation is inefficient. Indeed, the number of recursive calls to compute Fn is F(n+1).

My question is: what does "the number of recursive calls to compute Fn is F(n+1)" mean?

```
int F(int i)
{ 
  if (i < 1) return 0;
  if (i == 1) return 1;
  return F(i-1) + F(i-2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive implementation to compute fibonacci numbers takes F(n+1) recursive calls to compute the number F(n); i.e. to compute f(10)=55 you need 89 recursive calls, and 89 is F(11).

Answer (score 3):

If we want to compute Nth Fibonacci number F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2) .We can do it with iteration method and recursive method. if we do it with iterative method

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int a=0,b=1,c,i,n;
//clrscr();
printf("enter the limit of series\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n==0)
printf("%d\n",a);
else
printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
{
c=a+b;
printf("%d\n",c);
a=b;
b=c;
}

}
```

It takes O(n) time as it iterates from i=0 to N.

But with recursive method

```
int F(int i)
  { 
    if (i < 1) return 0;
    if (i == 1) return 1;
    return F(i-1) + F(i-2);
  }
```

The recurrence relation is

```
                     ___________ 0 if(n<=0) 
                    /___________ 1 if(n==1)
  Fibonacci(n) ____/
                   \
                    \___________ Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
```

So our problem for n =  sub-problem of (n-1) + sub-problem of (n-2)  hence our time function T(n) is as follows

```
   T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+O(1)
   T(n)={T(N-2)+T(n-3)}+T(n-2)  since T(n-1)=T(n-2)+T(n-3) -------- equation(1)
   from above you can see T(n-2) is calculated twice. If we expand the recursion tree for N=5 . The recursion tree is as follows


                                                       Fib(5)
                                                          |
                                    _____________________/ \__________________
                                   |                                          |
                                 Fib(4)                   +                 fib(3)    
                                   |                                          |
                           _______/ \_______                         ________/ \_______
                          |        +        |                        |        +        |
                       Fib(3)             Fib(2)                   Fib(2)           Fib(1)
                          |                  |                        |                
                  _______/ \____        ____/ \_______        _______/ \_____                   
                 |        +     |      |     +        |      |         +      |   
              Fib(2)        Fib(1)    Fib(1)      Fib(0)     Fib(1)        Fib(0)
         _______/ \_______
        |        +        |
      Fib(1)             Fib(0)
```

If we observe the recurrsion tree we find that Fib(1) is caliculated 5 times
                                               Fib(2) is caliculated 3 times
                                               Fib(3) is caliculated 2 times

So using recursion we are actually doing redundant computations . If you use iterative method these redudant calculations are avoided.

T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1

From previous SO post  [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

complexity of program is **approximately** equal to bigoh(2power(n)) .
Since O(n) < O(2powerN) recursive method is not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

"complexity of program is **approximately** equal to bigoh(2power(n)) .
Since O(n) < O(2powerN) recursive method is not efficient. "

If they compute this complexity in terms of the amount of recursive calls needed, then I don't know where they get 2^n. The graph doesn't model 2^n at all, for larger values the modeling decays significantly. By the 30th term of 832,040, it takes 2,692,536 recursive calls to compute it, far less than 2^30 which is over 1 billion. It's less than 1%!

Answer (score 0):

It means that to calculate the Fibonacci number of 10 numbers you need to run the recursion 10+1 times to obtain it. There are various algorithm that could improve this timeline.

Look at this post here which explains the time complexity of finding Fibonacci numbers and their improvement: [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: @chepner true, but that was not my point. I replied directly to what the question asked, which is F(n+1) and i just referred to n   :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my algo for fibonacci

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    // If we walk backwards in the fibonacci series, the values before
    // zero will be 1 and -1. i.e the series can be re imagined as 
    // -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3.
    // This will spare us from adding special handling for first 
    // and second element of the series  
    int a=-1,b=1,c,i,n;
    printf("enter the limit of series\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The series is : ");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=a+b;
        printf("%d\n",c);
        // move a and b forward
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some improved version of fibonacci where we compute fibonacci of number only once:

```
dicFib = { 0:0 ,1 :1 }
iterations = 0
def fibonacci(a):
    if  (a in dicFib):      
        return dicFib[a]    
    else :
        global iterations               
        fib = fibonacci(a-2)+fibonacci(a-1)
        dicFib[a] = fib
        iterations += 1
        return fib

print ("fibonacci of 10 is:" , fibonacci(10))
print ("fibonacci of all numbers:" ,dicFib)
print ("iterations:" ,iterations)

# ('fibonacci of 10 is:', 55)
# ('fibonacci of all numbers:', {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 8, 7: 13, 8: 21, 9: 34, 10: 55})
# ('iterations:', 9)
```

Here we are storing fibonnaci of each number in dictionary. So you can see it calculates only once for each iteration and for fibonacci(10) it is only 9 times.