# Java Time Complexity O(n^2/3)

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

My math background is not so good, this is my attempt to write the JAVA code with runtime proportion to different input .

1. With n^2/3. Since n^2/3 = cube root n * cube root n, hence I can write

   ```
   public void test(int n){
       for (int i = 0; i*i*i < n; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j*j*j < n; j++) {
               count ++;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. With 4^n. Can i use Fibonnaci method?

   ```
   public int fibonnaci(int n) {
       if (n <= 1) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return fibonnaci(n - 2) + fibonnaci(n - 1);
       }
   }
   ```

May I know if my code above is correct? thanks much!

Comment: 2) Fibonacci - It is more of O(2^n) iso O(n^4). Use 4 nested for loops (which run from 1 to n incremented by 1) as an example of O(n^4) ;-) and 1) is a clever example :)

Answer (score 5):

**The first one is correct**, and really well thought.

---

**The second one is not**. That algorithm to calculate fibs has much higher time complexity than O(n^4) (**EDIT**: *which was what was being asked when I wrote this answer -- the question has been updated meanwhile*). It is not even polynomial. The reasoning is as follows (notation #fib(x): number of times fib is called to calculate fib(x)):

- fib(1): #fib(1) = 1 (it returns directly the result)
- fib(2): #fib(2) = 3 (one for fib(2), which calls it for fib(0) and fib(1))
- fib(3): #fib(3) = 5 (one for fib(3), which calls it for fib(2) and fib(1), giving 3 + 1 more calls)
- fib(4): #fib(4) = 9
- fib(5): #fib(5) = 15
- fib(6): #fib(6) = 25
- ...
- fib(i): #fib(i) = 1 + #fib(i-1) + #fib(i-2)

So, you have:

- #fib(i) ~= #fib(i-1) + #fib(i-2)

From this, it would be a reasonable guess that calculating fib(i) takes "about" (actually, just a little less than) 2 times the time to calculate fib(i-1). Hence, you could "guess" that O(#fib(i)) = O(2^i). This is the correct answer, which you can prove easily by induction.

Just to finish about the Fibonacci Sequence, there are much faster algorithms to calculate the n-th number. For instance, an algorithm with linear time (ie, O(n)) is to memoize that function you wrote (ie, make it consult a Map to check if it know the result for n, is so return it immediately, otherwise, calculate it, store it and return it). There's also a **[closed formula to calculate the n-th fib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)**, therefore a constant-time algorithm (ie, O(1)).

---

Finally, **an example of O(n^4)** algorithm is anything with 4 inner loops, each loop running "about" n times.

For instance, calculate the volume of n cubes of side n (in a non-optimal way):

```
int volume = 0;
for (int cube = 0; cube < n; cube++)
  for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
      for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
        volume++;
return volume;
```

Comment: @LouisWasserman, well noted. However, when I answered the question, it was asked about n^4, the OP changed it later, after I wrote this. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just writing any code which takes time-complexity of that big-o bound?

Than for #1, yes, it would take `O(n^(2/3))`.

But for #2, your code would take `O(2^n)`, and `theta(1.6...^n)`, and 1.6.. is the famous golden-ratio number.

reference: [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but here is a sketch of a "cheat" solution to the problem of providing an example of a program that takes `O(F(N))` time;

1. Create a Java function object to evaluate `F(N)` for a given `N`:
2. Pass it as a parameter to the following method:

---

```
   public void computeOrderFN(int n, FunctionInt2Int fn) {
      int count = fn.evaluate(n);
      for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
          // Do something O(1) that the compiler can't optimize away)
      }
   }
```

---

But don't use this if that there is a risk of losing credit for being "a smart**s" :-)