# Big o notation and recursive functions

Tags: java, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to learn Big-O notation but i have difficulties in calculating time complexity of recursive functions.

Can you help me to understand the time complexity of following example?

```
public int recursiveFunction(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.max(recursiveFunction(rand(n)) + 2,recursiveFunction(n - 1));
}

public int rand(int n) {
    return new Random().nextInt(n - 1);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The result of your function is a *stack overflow* (and it is not a valid Java code)

Comment: ... and the theoretical complexity is O(∞). You recur unconditionally, you have no base case.

Comment: I know it is not a valid java code. It is something like pseudo code. I just want to learn the analysis.

Comment: updated code. result is not important.I just want to know that how many times does it run and what will be the time complexity.

Answer (score 5):

The time will depend on what `rand(n)` returns, but if you take the worst-case, this will be `n-2`. So the code simplifies to:

```
public int recursiveFunction(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.max(recursiveFunction(n - 2) + 2,recursiveFunction(n - 1));
}
```

which has an asymptotic upper bound equal to that of:

```
public int recursiveFunction(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    recursiveFunction(n-1);
    recursiveFunction(n-1);

    return 0;
}
```

which is a recursion with a depth of `n` and a branch factor of `2`, so O(2^n) time-complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive functions is not a good place to start learning about complexity. Even a relatively simple recursive function can require quite complex calculations to determine complexity.

For `recursiveFunction(n)`, you call `recursiveFunction(n-1)` and `recursiveFunction(a)` where `a < n-1`, so at worst that is `recursiveFunction(n-1)` once and `recursiveFunction(n-2)` once. That has the same complexity as a Fibonacci series, [it's complexity is O(2^n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/1711796). You'll note the algorithm in the link looks very similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know the simple calculations,but it is hard to understand the one with recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have no understood the problem of your code. Because your code creates random values its runtime complexity cannot be determined. Because of your '+2' and '-1' it is also possible for the program to never end. However, this is not likely but possible, thus one can only say it is O(infinite).

Usual cases of the bigO notation:

**You have only one loop:**

```
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {}
```

this comes to O(n), because you have n iterations

**Two or more loops in sequence:**

```
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {}
for(int l=0;l<n;++l) {}
```

comes to O(2*n), but constants do not matter on bigO, so it is O(n)

**Entangled loops:**

```
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {
    for(int l=0;l<n;++l) {
    }
}
```

is O(n²),

```
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {
    for(int l=0;l<n;++l) {
        for(int m=0;m<n;++m) {
        }
    }
}
```

is O(n³) and so on

And **the most common complexity you will encounter** for search/comparison algorithms is

```
for(int k=0;k<n;++k) {
    for(int l=k;l<n;++l) {// note here: l=k instead of l=0
    }
}
```

Is O(n*log(n))

For more details use google.

Comment: (1) `for(int k=0;k<n;++k) for(int l=k;l<n;++l) ...` is O(n^2). (2.a) `rand(n)` can never return a value greater than n-2, and (2.b) the `+2` doesn't matter since it's just added to the output of `recursiveFunction` to determine the return value, so the algorithm will terminate (in O(2^n), see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You picked a rather tricky problem here. The calculation with Math.Max doesn't matter much, what matters is the two recursive calls.

There's a problem here when n == 1 because you call rand (1), which calls Random().nextInt (0) which is not defined - it is supposed to return a random integer which is >= 0 and < 0 which is not possible. Let's hope it returns 0 - if not, we are in trouble.

recursiveFunction (n) calls recursiveFunction (n - 1), and makes another call recursiveFunction (i) with a random i, 0 <= i <= n - 2. Let's make a table of the maximum number of calls that are made, counting 1 for the initial call (assuming rand (1) returns 0, and every other call returns n - 2):

```
n = 0: 1 calls
n = 1: 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 calls
n = 2: 1 + 1 + 3 = 5 calls
n = 3: 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 calls
n = 4: 1 + 5 + 9 = 15 calls
n = 5: 1 + 9 + 15 = 25 calls
n = 6: 1 + 15 + 25 = 41 calls
n = 7: 1 + 25 + 41 = 67 calls
n = 8: 1 + 41 + 67 = 109 calls
n = 9: 1 + 67 + 109 = 177 calls
n = 10: 1 + 109 + 177 = 287 calls
```

The number of calls grow fast, but not quite as fast as 2^n. I'd say it is O (c^n) with c = sqrt (1.25) + 0.5. That's the worst case; average is a lot less.