# a better guess on upper bound

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

It's a question from 《introduction to algorithms》whose number is 4.4-5 and is described like this:

> Use a recursion tree to determine a good asymptotic upper bound on the recurrence T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n.Use the substitution method to verify your answer.

I found it is difficult to me to calculate the recursion tree's recurrence. The answer I gave

> Math.pow(2,n)

seems too loose.Maybe there is some better guess existed.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `n` an integer, and if so, does `n/2` round down?

Comment: Accept some answers to some of the questions you asked. People are less inclined to help people who don't give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @Dukeling:Thank you.I haven't noticed this actually.I will keep this in mind.Really appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Tinctorius:Yeah.N is an integer.We'd better round n/2 up.

Comment: @tuanlong: Up instead of down? Ok :/ Then `T(1) = T(0) + T(1/2) + 1 = T(0) + T(1) + 1`, so `T(0) = -1`. But what is `T(1)` then?

Comment: @Tinctorius:T(0) not existed.T(1) is a constant.You'd better review chapter 4 of 《introduction to algorithms》, then you will know what I mean better.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tuanlong: And what about the many people who do not own a copy of that book? Are they just supposed to guess the information missing from your question?

Comment: @Tinctorius:I'm sorry to make you unhappy and I really apprecited your help since I have got a lot of help here.I also wish I can use what I have learned here to help anyone someday.I just mean to say that if you have read that chapter you will understand this question more deeply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope I did no mistakes :)

let's `A(n)=T(n/2)+n`

```
0. T(n)=T(n-1)+A(n)=T(n-2)+A(n-1)+A(n)=...=A(1)+A(2)+...+A(n)
   T(n)=sum[1..n]A(n)
   T(n)=sum[i=1..n]T(i/2)+sum[i=1..n]i
```

assuming `n/2` is integer division, `T(n/2)=T((n+1)/2)` for even `n`, so the first sum consists of two equal halves: `T(1)+T(1)+T(2)+T(2)+...`

```
1. T(n)=2*sum[1..n/2]T(i)+n*(n-1)/2
```

since `T(n)<=T(m) for every n<=m`

```
2. T(n)<=n*T(n/2)+n*(n-1)/2
```

since `T(n/2)>=n/2>=(n-1)/2`

```
3. T(n)<=n*T(n/2)+n*T(n/2)=2*n*T(n/2)
```

let's consider this for only `n=2^k`, since `T` is monotonous: `n=2^k` and `U(k)=T(2^k)`

```
4. U(k)<=2*(2^k)*U(k-1)=2^(k+1)*U(k-1)
```

let `L(k)=log2 U(k)`

```
5. L(k)<=k+1+L(k-1)
```

just like we did between step0 and step1

```
6. L(k)<=k*(k-1)/2+k=k*k/2-k/2+k<=k*k

7. U(k)=2^L(k)<=2^squared(k)

8. T(n)=U(log2 n)<=2^squared(log2 n)
```

Comment: +1 Clever! I couldn't find a solution but it seems like you did! I am still a bit lost though, could you please explain your first step. :)

Comment: I've added some details for the first step

Comment: it seems the upper bound can be improved even more - I've updated items after #3.

Comment: Thank you very much, really surprised to see your answer since I haven't come here for several days.I had been thinking no one would help me to resolve this question.It's really a grate place here.

Comment: After step 2 , why you took n*T(n/2) instead of n/2*T(n/2)? Also after step 3 only can not we can try to solve the recurrence? Which will.come out to be n^logn/(2^((lgn*(1+lgn)/2))).

Answer (score 1):

The recursion relation seems to give rise to a sub-exponential and super-linear computation-time, which means that any chosen base would work as an upper bound given a large enough `n`.

Your choice of `2^n` is a good answer and possibly the one they were looking for in the book. It is a simple solution that is valid even for quite small values of `n`. (Still, I understand why you are asking the question because it does grow much faster than `T(n)` even for moderately large `n`.)

Given `T(1) = 1` (or some other constant) the recursion equation gives us the running time as follows for the first few values of `n`.

```
T(1) = 1          n^1 = 2
T(2) = 4          n^2 = 4
T(3) = 11         n^3 = 8
T(4) = 19         n^4 = 16
T(5) = 35         n^5 = 32
T(6) = 52         n^6 = 64
T(7) = 78         n^7 = 128
T(8) = 105        n^8 = 256
T(9) = 149        n^9 = 512
```

We can see that the choice of `2^n` as an upper limit is valid for all values `T(6)` and above.

If you want a lower bound than `2^n` you could choose a lower base (with the trade-off that it will only be valid for higher numbers of `n`). But I must add that it will still be basically the same solution as the one you already have.

Any base larger than one would do but to be a bit more specific we could for example see that the recursion equation `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n` is bounded by the equation `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)` for `n>5`.

This is the same recursion relation as for the Fibonacci sequence and following the steps in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) question it has a computational complexity matching the golden ratio `(1+sqrt(5))/2 = 1,618` to the power of `n`.

Plotting the actual values we can see for which `n` the value of `T(n)` is bounded by `((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n`. From the figure it seems to be values `n=13` and above.

[image: Computational complexity of algorithm.]

All this said, I have thought a bit about approximating the running time with some sub-exponential function. It doesn't seem like it can be easily done and as I said I believe you have found the expected answer.

Comment: Thanks for your analisis.I have contributed here less while having got a lot of kindness here.I need to grow more fast and be able to help anyone needs help as soon as possible.

Comment: @tuanlong You are welcome! (Even if my answer was not totally correct.) :) I can see that you have not cast any votes. I would recommend that you go through your questions and up-vote answers that have helped you. Up-voting and accepting answers is a good way to show your appreciation here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have been here not for a long time and noticed functions of "accept" and "vote" recently.I will try them, thank you.