# Complexity of an algorithm with two recursive calls

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have a strange algorithm than is being called recursively 2 times. It's

```
int alg(int n)
   loop body = Θ(3n+1)
   alg(n-1);
   alg(n-2)
```

Somehow i need to find this algorithm's complexity. I've tried to find it with using characteristic polynomial of the above equation but the result system is too hard to solve so i was wondering if there was any other straight way..

Comment: This is similar to the complexity of [recursive Fibonacci sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/q/360748/1805388).

Comment: Iam not so sure. I mean it's easy to calculate Fibonacci complexity, but now with this loop body = Θ(3n+1) it makes it much harder.

Comment: What's your terminal condition?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to tell, terminal condition is n = 0

Comment: It's similar in the sense that your algorithm is at least as complex, so it is sufficient to conclude that your algorithm also has exponential complexity.

Comment: Nothing strange about this. This is how Fibonacci series is implemented. Google it. You should get it easily.

Comment: It is exponential as implemented. As long as `alg` is idempotent, though, it can be implemented as quadratic.

Comment: If you go for i from 0 to n and storing the results, this algorithm can be done in linear time and space, assuming no side effects of the algorithm and leaving he loop body part away. with it, it's obviously quadratic.

Comment: if you memoize it you can also make it linear time.

Answer (score 4):

Complexity:  `alg(n) = Θ(φ^n)` where φ = Golden ratio = `(1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`

I can't formally prove it at first, but with a night's work, I find my missing part - *The substitution method* with ***subtracting*** a lower-order term. Sorry for my bad expression of provement (∵ poor English).

---

Let `loop body = Θ(3n+1) ≦ tn`

Assume (guess) that `cφ^n ≦  alg(n)  ≦ dφ^n - 2tn` for an `n (n ≧ 4)`

Consider `alg(n+1)`:

```
 Θ(n) + alg(n) + alg(n-1) ≦ alg(n+1) ≦ Θ(n) + alg(n)     + alg(n-1)
    c * φ^n + c * φ^(n-1) ≦ alg(n+1) ≦ tn   + dφ^n - 2tn + dφ^(n-1) - 2t(n-1)
              c * φ^(n+1) ≦ alg(n+1) ≦ tn   + d * φ^(n+1) - 4tn + 2
              c * φ^(n+1) ≦ alg(n+1) ≦ d * φ^(n+1) - 3tn + 2
              c * φ^(n+1) ≦ alg(n+1) ≦ d * φ^(n+1) - 2t(n+1)  (∵ n ≧ 4)
```

So it is correct for `n + 1`. By mathematical induction, we can know that it's correct for all `n`.

So `cφ^n ≦  alg(n)  ≦ dφ^n - 2tn` and then `alg(n) = Θ(φ^n)`.

Comment: Problem: How can you throw away O(n) at the last step, on the right most part `Θ(n) + d * φ^(n+1)` --> `d * φ^(n+1)`?

Comment: @nhahtdh I said it's not *formal* because I couldn't remember how I can throw it away. Now I remembered and updated my answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer I learned ***substitution method***, actually mathematical induction, from Introduction to Algorithm, 3ed. I hope my updated answer is formal enough.

Comment: It sure is. Now I have to update my answer to not give a wrong impression of yours to casual readers ;)

Answer (score 3):

[johnchen902](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040040/johnchen902) is correct:

> `alg(n)=Θ(φ^n)` where `φ = Golden ratio = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`

<del>but his argument is a bit too hand-waving, so let's make it strict.</del> His original argument was incomplete, therefore I added mine, but now [he has completed the argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508300/1011995).

---

```
loop body = Θ(3n+1)
```

Let us denote the cost of the loop body for the argument `n` with `g(n)`. Then `g(n) ∈ Θ(n)` since `Θ(n) = Θ(3n+1)`.

Further, let `T(n)` be the total cost of `alg(n)` for `n >= 0`. Then, for `n >= 2` we have the recurrence

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + g(n)
```

For `n >= 3`, we can insert the recurrence applied to `T(n-1)` into that,

```
T(n) = 2*T(n-2) + T(n-3) + g(n) + g(n-1)
```

and for `n > 3`, we can continue, applying the recurrence to `T(n-2)`. For sufficiently large `n`, we therefore have

```
T(n) = 3*T(n-3) + 2*T(n-4) + g(n) + g(n-1) + 2*g(n-2)
     = 5*T(n-4) + 3*T(n-5) + g(n) + g(n-1) + 2*g(n-2) + 3*g(n-3)
     ...
                                       k-1
     = F(k)*T(n+1-k) + F(k-1)*T(n-k) +  ∑ F(j)*g(n+1-j)
                                       j=1

                                 n-1
     = F(n)*T(1) + F(n-1)*T(0) +  ∑ F(j)*g(n+1-j)
                                 j=1
```

with the Fibonacci numbers `F(n)` [`F(0) = 0, F(1) = F(2) = 1`].

`T(0)` and `T(1)` are some constants, so the first part is obviously `Θ(F(n))`. It remains to investigate the sum.

Since `g(n) ∈ Θ(n)`, we only need to investigate

```
       n-1
A(n) =  ∑ F(j)*(n+1-j)
       j=1
```

Now,

```
                 n-1
A(n+1) - A(n) =   ∑ F(j) + (((n+1)+1) - ((n+1)-1))*F((n+1)-1)
                 j=1

                n-1
              =  ∑ F(j)  + 2*F(n)
                j=1

              = F(n+1) - 1 + 2*F(n)
              = F(n+2) + F(n) - 1
```

Summing that, starting with `A(2) = 2 = F(5) + F(3) - 5`, we obtain

```
A(n) = F(n+3) + F(n+1) - (n+3)
```

and therefore, with

```
c*n <= g(n) <= d*n
```

the estimate

```
F(n)*T(1) + F(n-1)*T(0) + c*A(n) <= T(n) <= F(n)*T(1) + F(n-1)*T(0) + d*A(n)
```

for `n >= 2`. Since `F(n+1) <= A(n) < F(n+4)`, all terms depending on `n` in the left and right parts of the inequality are `Θ(φ^n)`, q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions:**

1: `n >= 0`

2: `Θ(3n+1) = 3n + 1`

**Complexity:**

```
O(2 ^ n * (3n - 2));
```

**Reasoning:**

```
int alg(int n)
   loop body = Θ(3n+1)// for every n you have O(3n+1)
   alg(n-1);
   alg(n-2)
```

Assuming the alg does not execute for n < 1, you have the following repetitions:

**Step n:**

```
3 * n + 1
alg(n - 1) => 3 * (n - 1) + 1
alg(n - 2) => 3 * (n - 2) + 1
```

Now you basically have a division. You have to imagine a number tree with N as parent and n-1 and n-2 as children.

```
                                       n
                 n-1                                  n-2
          n - 2        n - 3                     n - 3       n - 4
     n - 3   n - 4   n - 4 n - 5              n - 4 n - 5  n - 5  n - 6
    n-4 n-5 | n-5 n-6 |n-5 n-6 |n-6 n-7    n-5 n-6 n-6 n-7  n-6 n-6| n-6 n-8
```

It's obvious that there is a repetition pattern here. For every pair `(n - k, n - k - 1) in A = {k, with k from 0 to n)` except the first two and the last two, `(n - 1, n - 2) and (n-2, n-3)` there is a `3k + 1 * (2 ^ (k - 1))` complexity.

I am looking at the number of repetitions of the pair `(n - k, n - k - 1)`. So now for each `k` from `0 to n` I have:

```
(3k + 1) * (2 ^ (k - 1)) iterations.
```

If you sum this up from 1 to n you should get the desired result. I will expand the expression:

```
(3k + 1) * (2 ^ (k - 1)) = 3k * 2 ^ (k - 1) + 2 ^ (k - 1)
```

**Update**

```
1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^n = 2 ^ (n + 1) - 1
```

In your case, this winds up being:

```
2^n - 1
```

Based on the summation formula and k = 0, n . Now the first one:

```
3k * 2 ^ (k - 1)
```

This is equal to 3 sum from `k = 0, n of k * 2 ^ (k - 1)`.
That sum can be determined by switching to polinomial functions, integrating, contracting using the `1 + a ^ 2 + a ^ 3 + ... + a ^ n` formula, and then differentiated again to obtain the result, which is `(n - 1) * 2 ^ n + 1`.

So you have:

```
2 ^ n - 1 + 3 * (n - 1) * 2 ^ n + 1
```

Which contracted is:

```
2 ^ n * (3n - 2);
```

Comment: That's smth wrong: let Θ(n) = 0. Then we go to Fibonacci Sequence. And its complexity is exponential. But your complexity is polynomial.

Comment: Also, do you think if it is correct assumption, that `Θ(n) = n`?

Comment: In the question "loop body = Θ(3n+1)". You assume that `Θ(3n+1) = 3n+1`, but it could be `1.5*(3n+1)`  or `3n+1  + exp(-n)`, for example.

Comment: It is interesting for me, why it is correct. At lest, it is not obvious. (Also I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

The body of the function takes `Θ(n)` time.
The function is called twice recursively.

For the given function the complexity is,

```
     T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + cn        -----  1
     T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + c(n-1)  -----  2

1-2 ->   T(n) = 2T(n-1) - T(n-3) + c        -----  3

3 -->    T(n-1) = 2T(n-2) + T(n-4) + c      -----  4

3-4 ->   T(n) = 3T(n-1) - 2T(n-2) - T(n-3) - T(n-4) ----- 5
```

Let `g(n) = 3g(n-1)`

There for, we can approximate `T(n) = O(g(n))`

g(n) is **Θ(3<sup>n</sup>)**

There for **T(n) = O(3<sup>n</sup>)**

Comment: What you have is upper bound, but I don't think this is tight upper bound.