# Variable in a recurrence relation

Tags: analysis, recurrence

if f(n,k) + f(n,k-1) = c1 * f(n-1,k-1) + c2 * f(n-1,k-2) then
what should be c1 and c2 in terms of big O notation.
Are they polynomial in k or constant?

I am not able to expand this recurrence properly.

Comment: Is it a misprint that you have f(n,k) in both parts?

Comment: it was a miss print thanks for correction

Comment: Your equation seems even more complex that fibonacci equation, so it is at least expponential. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: I do not want time complexity, I need to know what can be possible value for c1 and c2