# Smalltalk Fibonacci

Tags: for-loop, syntax, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have to use Smalltalk to return the n<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number, I haven't used this language before. This program returns 1 to any input and I don't know why. It didn't even iterate the for loop I think. Could someone help me? Thanks.

```
'Which fibonacci number do you want? (n>2)' printNl.
n := stdin nextLine asInteger.

(n <= 2)
    ifTrue: ['Type a larger number, F(1) and F(2) equals 1!' displayNl.]
    ifFalse: [  
        result:= 1.
        parent := 1.
        gparent := 1.   
        2 to: n do: [ :i | [
                result := (parent + gparent).
                gparent := parent.
                parent := result.
                'come on, do something' displayNl.
            ]
        ].
        result displayNl.
    ].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra set of brackets in your loop body, which makes it create (but not execute) a block on each loop iteration.  Here's what you meant to write:

```
    2 to: n do: [ :i |
        result := (parent + gparent).
        gparent := parent.
        parent := result.
        'come on, do something' displayNl.
    ].
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify it even more if you want:

```
a := b := 1.
(n - 1) timesRepeat: [a := b + (b := a)].
```

The semi symmetric "ratchet" expression inside the block is one of my all time Smalltalk favorites. Not necessarily going to win readability contests, but I think it is cool looking. It drives home the strictly left to right rules of Smalltalk, whereas in other languages we'd want to mentally evaluate the rightmost assignment before placing the (original) value of `b` in the receiver position.

Notice also how I replaced your `2 to: n do:` expression, since you're not using the `i` argument variable.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you define a method

```
fib
  ^ self < 2
    ifTrue: [ 1 ]
    ifFalse: [ (self - 2) fib + (self - 1) fib ]
```

in the *Integer* class and use it to calculate the sequence?

1. Smalltalk is not a procedural language, you shouldn't write just a long script in one method.
2. Use the beauty of recursion

Comment: [Unfortunately, the beauty of recursion produces an extremely inefficient (exponential-time) implementation of the Fibonacci function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) while a correct iterative solution runs in linear time.

Comment: @robmayoff **appl3r** is asking about the implementation and not about "optimised implementation". You know that simple rule: 1) make it run, 2) make it right, 3) make it fast. I won't argue that this is not optimal, but I think that this is important for author to understand how objects and messages work. Otherwise we can all program in RISC commands

Comment: What I don't understand is, why my program is not working, while it should. :/
I had a version with recursive calls and it is working fine, but what I need is an iterative implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
fib := [:n |
        (n<=1)
            ifTrue: [n]
            ifFalse:
                [
                    (fib value: (n-1)) +
                    (fib value: (n-2))
                ]
    ].
fib value 10
```

for VisualWorks

Answer (score 0):

```
(1 to: n)
inject: OrderedCollection new
into: [ :coll :each |
    | p pp n |
    p := coll at: (each - 1) ifAbsent: [ 0 ].
    pp := coll at: (each - 2) ifAbsent: [ 0 ].
    n := p + pp.
    ((n = 0) and: [ each = 1 ])
        ifTrue: [ n := 1 ].
    coll 
        add: n;
        yourself ].
```

In Pharo.