# Time complexity of a function?

Tags: function, time, big-o, complexity-theory

What are the steps I need to take to work out the time complexity of this function in terms of N? Or any function?

I'm essentially asking how to evaluate algorithm complexity in Big O notation?

```
int f(int N) {

if (N<2) return 1;

return f(N-1)+f(N-2);

}
```

Comment: Can at least try to show some effort in the solution or how you approached the problem? Otherwise this looks like a homework question.

Comment: I'm not looking for the answer just want to know what steps to take. You can even use a different method. Thanks

Comment: So the question is about how to evaluate algorithm complexity in Big O notation, instead of the performance of the Fibonacci algorithm? I'm confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) — the accepted answer goes into **LOTS** of detail.

Comment: See also "[*How to find time complexity of an algorithm*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015/1364007)" for some more info.