# Big(O) of recursive n choose k code

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, combinations

Is the big(O) of the following recursive code simply O(n choose k)?

```
int nchoosek(int n, int k) {
    if (n == k) return 1;
    if (k == 0) return 1;
    return nchoosek(n-1, k) + nchoosek(n-1, k-1);
}
```

Comment: Did you draw a tree?

Comment: The code is very similar to Fibonacci sequence code, so I'll leave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence/360773#360773) here.

Comment: @erip Using a tree, I figured that it might be 2^n, but from the mathematical calculations to obtain nchoosek, it seems to be bounded by n! instead

Comment: Note that 2^n is O(n!).

Comment: However, what was somehow counterintuitive to me:  n! is o(2^(2^n))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the notation is correct but I guess you can write the recurrence for this function like

```
T(n) = T(n-1, k) + T(n-1, k-1) + O(1)
```

Since you have two possible paths we just have to analyse the worst case of each and choose the slowest.

**Worst case of `T(n-1, k)`**

Given that `0<k<n` and `k` is as far as possible from `n` then we have

```
T(n-1, k) = T(n-1) = O(n)
```

**Worst case of `T(n-1, k-1)`**

We need `0<k<n` and `k` should be as close to `n` as possible. Then

```
T(n-1, k-1) = T(n-1) = O(n)
```

Therefore `T(n, k) = 2*O(n) + O(1) = O(n)`

Another way of seeing this is by reducing the problem to other known problems, for example you can solve the same problem by using the definition of the choose function in terms of the Factorial function:

```
nCk = n!/k!(n-k)!
```

The running time of the Factorial is `O(n)` even in the recursive case.

`nCk` requires calculating the Factorial three times:

```
n! => O(n)
k! => O(k) = O(n)
(n-k)! => O(n-k) = O(n)
```

Then the multiplication and division are both constant time `O(1)`, hence the running time is:

```
T(n) = 3*O(n) + 2*O(1) = O(n)
```