# How to calculate the complexity of a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

What's the most intuitive way to calculate the time and space complexity (Big O notation) of the following recursive function?

```
function count(str) {
  if (str.length <= 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  var firstTwoDigits = parseInt(str.slice(0, 2), 10);

  if (firstTwoDigits <= 26) {
    return count(str.slice(1)) +
           count(str.slice(2));
  }

  return count(str.slice(1));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for my prev answer, Complexity of your code seems to be

**O(2^N)** or **O(2^N-1)** to be precise in worst case scenario.

So, If

```
N = str.length ;//number of iteration
```

In the worst case scenario, your `str` consists of all N digits of either 1 or 2.

Then, If **N is 20** to begin with, then it will spawn two more recursive calls of **N= 18** and **N = 19**,

Then, **N = 19** will spawn two more calls (and so one till value of N is 0 )

So, the number of calls will increase exponentially with each iteration), hence coming to the value (2^N - 1).

Comment: @Thilo Please check now

Comment: Definitely. More precisely the complexity consists in a Fibonacci series.

Comment: @dgiugg yes, it looks quite close doesn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Yes, the worst case is exactly a Fibonacci suite. The mean case is the same with different coefficients : Fn+2 = Fn+1 + 3/4Fn. The 3/4 is for 26/100 cases with the comparison to 26.