# Calculating Fibonacci numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fibonacci, series, memoization

While doing [Project Euler Problem 25](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-25-fibonacci-sequence-1000-digits/), I came across various techniques to compute the nth Fibonacci number. Memoization seemed to be the fastest amongst them all, and intuitively, I expected memoization to be faster than creating a list from bottom-up.

The code for the two functions is:

```
def fib3(n): #FASTEST YET
    fibs= [0,1] #list from bottom up
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        fibs.append(fibs[-1]+fibs[-2])
    return fibs[n]

def fib4(n, computed= {0:0, 1:1}): #memoization
    if n not in computed:
        computed[n]= fib4(n-1, computed)+ fib4(n-2, computed)
    return computed[n]
print fib3(1000)
print fib4(1000)
```

fib3 was approximately 8 times faster than fib4. I am unable to figure out the reason behind this. Essentially both are storing the values as they compute, one in a list, the other in a dictionary so that they can access them as "cached" later. Why the huge difference?

Comment: Jeez... who down voted this question??? Take a deep breath and a chill pill! Or at least explain your move.

Comment: `fib4` is recursive (calls itself). Recursion is expensive.

Comment: The best use of memoization shows up when you repeat the function call a number of times. If you repeatedly call fib3 / fib4, you'll find fib4 will be faster

Comment: @KlausD. *`Recursion is expensive.`* -- I'm not sure if this sentence correct. For calculating *Fibonacci* numbers, this is probably often true, but I found an interesting [counterexample in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38784246/2932052)

Comment: @Wolf The example in that link does recursion rarely, so the recursion has a minimal impact on the runtime.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes but only for ***some*** arguments ;)

Comment: @Wolf Well, you got an other answer there why you measurement was not representative.

Comment: @KlausD. Well thanks for having a look on it. I by chance stumbled upon your comment when I has this shocking experience yesterday and so I now decided to post it as a question. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Developing on thesonyman101: `my_list[i]` gives you immediate access to the element while `my_dict[key]` requires to compute the hash function and checking for collisions before looking what's in the bucket. Also your memoization sets up some potentially deep recursion stack which has some cost too.

Even faster (provided you don't need to recompute several values, which I know is not the case for Euler problems :) is to only keep track of the last 2 terms. So you don't wast any list management cost.

Comment: What will the code look like if I keep track of only the last two terms?

Comment: Something like (in the `for` loop) `fib_n, fib_n_minus_1 = fib_n + fib_n_minus_1, fib_n`

Answer (score -1):

You are using recursion in fib4 function. Which is exponential in terms of time complexity

EDIT after some one said memorize makes fib4 linear: 
Except it does not.

The memorize thing works to reduce calculation time for repetitive calls only. For the first time the Fibonacci value of a number n is calculated by only recursion.

Try this out yourself

```
import timeit

setup ='''
def fib3(n): #FASTEST YET
    fibs= [0,1] #list from bottom up
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        fibs.append(fibs[-1]+fibs[-2])
    return fibs[n]

def fib4(n, computed= {0:0, 1:1}): #memoization
    if n not in computed:
        computed[n]= fib4(n-1, computed)+ fib4(n-2, computed)
    return computed[n]

'''

print (min(timeit.Timer('fib3(600)', setup=setup).repeat(3, 1)))

print (min(timeit.Timer('fib4(600)', setup=setup).repeat(3, 1)))
```

This will show fib4 taking longer.

```
0.00010111480978441638
0.00039419570581368307
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

If you change the last two lines, that is repeat each for 100 times, the result changes Now fib4 becomes faster, as if not only no recursion, almost like no additional time to compute at all

```
print (min(timeit.Timer('fib3(600)', setup=setup).repeat(3, 100)))

print (min(timeit.Timer('fib4(600)', setup=setup).repeat(3, 100)))
```

Results with 50 repeats

```
0.00501430622506104
0.00045805769094068097
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Results with 100 repeats

```
0.01583016969421893
0.0006815746388851851
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: The memoization makes the recursion take only linear time.

Comment: @hugomg and how would that be without expanded allocation of memory ?

Comment: Yes, memoisation is about using some extra memory to reduce the time needed. In OP's case the `computed` dictionary is gonna cost O(n) memory to reduce the runtime of the recursive function from O(2^n) to O(n)

Comment: I read about this but - there are additional costs in still calculating fibs through the whole cycle from n to 1 recursively (except the last part that is memorized). It definitely is still more expensive than a for loop.

Comment: Every fib function is gonna have to calculate the whole cycle from 1 to n to calculate fib(n). (unless you use that formula with the golden ratio but that would be a totally different algorithm)

Comment: Incorrect.. I tried to run 1000 with fib 4 and get this error 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
So it is still "recursive" and hence not linear. This is in python 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120202/discussion-between-santanu-dey-and-hugomg).

Comment: Exactly what i thought. memoization can be faster, but there's a requirement. CACHING or filling up of Look-up table. until that's done, it's just plane old recrusion. SLOW!.

Answer (score -2):

take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence).

as you can see, the complexity of fibonacci algorithm(with recursion) comes out to be approximately O(2^n).

while for the `fib3` it'll be O(n).

now you can compute, if your input size is 3, `fib3` will have a complexity of O(3) but `fib4` will have it O(8).

you can see, why it's slower.

Comment: fib4 is also O(n) because of the memoization. If it were exponential he wouldn't have been able to print fib4(1000) to compare it with fib3.

Comment: @hugomg but while we go lower into the the call stack, wouldn't memoization be useless? fib4(1000) will in turn call fib4(999) and fib4(998) but neither of these functions have a value stored in lookup table. memoization will only be useful when we go up the call stack since by then every fn call from fib4(1) would have it's value stored in look up table. won't it?