# Surprised about good recursion performance in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, recursion

I wrote this rather poor Python function for prime factorization:

```
import math

def factor(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+1)):
        if not n % i:
            return [i] + factor(n//i)
    return [n]
```

and it worked as expected, now I was interested in whether the performance could be better when using an iterative approach:

```
def factor_it(n):
    r = []
    i = 2
    while i < int(math.sqrt(n)+1):
        while not n % i:
            r.append(i)
            n //= i
        i +=1
    if n > 1:
        r.append(n)
    return r
```

But what I observed (while the functions gave the same results) was that the iterative function took longer to run. At least I had the feeling, when doing this:

```
number = 31123478114123
print(factor(number))
print(factor_it(number))
```

so I measured:

```
setup = '''
import math

def factor(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+1)):
        if not n % i:
            return [i] + factor(n//i)
    return [n]

def factor_it(n):
    r = []
    i = 2
    while i < int(math.sqrt(n)+1):
        while not n % i:
            r.append(i)
            n //= i
        i +=1
    if n > 1:
        r.append(n)
    return r
'''

import timeit

exec(setup)

number = 66666667*952381*290201
print(factor(number))
print(factor_it(number))

print(timeit.Timer('factor('+str(number)+')',setup=setup).repeat(1,1))
print(timeit.Timer('factor_it('+str(number)+')',setup=setup).repeat(1,1))
```

And this is what I got:

```
[290201, 952381, 66666667]
[290201, 952381, 66666667]
[0.19888348945642065]
[0.7451271022307537]
```

Why is the recursive approach in this case faster than the iterative one?

<sup>I use WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2 (Python 3.4.4 64bits).</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s because you’re recomputing `sqrt` each time. This modification runs as fast as your recursive version:

```
def factor_it2(n):
    r = []
    i = 2
    lim = int(math.sqrt(n)+1)
    while i < lim:
        while not n % i:
            r.append(i)
            n //= i
        lim = int(math.sqrt(n)+1)
        i += 1
    if n > 1:
        r.append(n)
    return r
```

`timeit` gives me these times:

```
factor      0.13133816363922143
factor_it   0.5705408816539869
factor_it2  0.14267319543853973
```

I think the tiny difference that remains is due to `for … in range(…)` being faster than the equivalent `while` loop, as the `for` loop can use a generator instead of having to execute a bunch of comparisons.

Comment: Hey, great! But interestingly not  completely as fast ;)

Comment: There is **still a performance gap** despite the square root is calculated just as often in both functions.

Comment: @Wolf Well, that depends. You are comparing a "recursive" function with *3* calls. That is unfair. Just choose a number like `number = 2**8 * 3**4 * 4**3 * 5**2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 15` and tables turn.

Comment: @MariusSiuram Good point! Well, but... how can I know this before when factoring unknown numbers? But you are right, maybe I should look on probabilities and accept this answer. On the other hand, there may be languages that have cheap recursion and expensive variables.

Comment: @Wolf first thing I think would be: do not `factor` in python --at least not in Python interpreter, do a C extension, Cython or something like that. In the title you were asking about "recursion performance" and I want to claim that talking about "recursion" for a 3-depth test is somewhat unexpected. Of couse you are right, for this specific example the performance is strange and also there are languages with cheap recursion (maybe Erlang? if I recall correctly). But for Python deep recursive functions, swap to iterative algorithms.

Comment: @MariusSiuram Yes, I thought of Erlang. I'm not factoring really big numbers, so pythons performance is absolutely sufficient for my needs (I know C/C++ but hate its overhead when I try to just check something). I was just "shocked" that performance hit happened. (I still fully overlooked the sqrt call when asking the question.)