# why my code is slow when finding Fibonacci sum?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, fibonacci

I'm writing answers for [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) Questions [in this repo](https://github.com/Hondoga/projectEuler_Solutions)
but having some performance issues in my solution

**Question 2:**
 Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. 
 By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
 By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My Solution is

```
func solution2()
{
    func fibonacci(number: Int) -> (Int)
    {
        if number <= 1
        {
            return number
        }
        else
        {
            return fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2)
        }
    }

    var sum = 0

    print("calculating...")
    for index in 2..<50
    {
        print (index)
        if (fibonacci(index) % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += fibonacci(index)
        }
    }

    print(sum)
}
```

My Question is, why it gets super slow after iteration 42, i want to do it for 4000000 as the question says, any help?

solution 2

```
func solution2_fast()
{
    var phiOne : Double = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0
    var phiTwo : Double = (1.0 - sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0

    func findFibonacciNumber (nthNumber : Double) -> Int64
    {
        let nthNumber : Double = (pow(phiOne, nthNumber) - (pow(phiTwo, nthNumber))) / sqrt(5.0)
        return Int64(nthNumber)
    }

    var sum : Int64 = 0

    print("calculating...")
    for index in 2..<4000000
    {
        print (index)
        let f = findFibonacciNumber(Double(index))
        if (f % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += f
        }
    }

    print(sum)

}
```

Comment: Your code is slow, not Swift. Think about recursion and redundant calculations.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen, the way you implemented it makes it explode exponentially.  Each N-th number is re-calculating (N-1)-th and (N-2)-th numbers.  And consequetely (N-1)-th will recalculate (N-2)-th and (N-3), etc, etc.  Basically, your cost to calculate a Fibonacchi around 4 mio is a function agains 4-mio too.

Comment: ok, I edited the title to
[why my code is slow when finding Fibonacci sum?]

Comment: Watch the WWDC 2014 Video Advanced Swift Session 404. There is a great explanation (and a solution)

Comment: please see the second solution, it goes to 91 and crashes :(
ok, will see the wwdc video

Comment: @DeyaEldeen: Read PE#2 again. It does *not* say "the first 4 million Fibonacci numbers" ...

Comment: 92 exceeds the limit of `Int(64)` and causes an overflow.

Comment: Recursive Fibonacci is slow because it's computational complexity grow  exponentially: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/6319106

Comment: You are calculating the sum of the first 4 million Fibonacci numbers. The question asks for the sum of all Fibonacci numbers less than 4 million. This is very different. Don't make the question more difficult than it already is.

Comment: You can find a very, very sophisticated algorithm [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39493/more-efficient-solution-for-project-euler-2-sum-of-fibonacci-numbers-under-4-m) (**Simplified algorithm** at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing about PE questions is to think about what it is asking.

This is not asking you to produce all Fibonacci numbers F(n) less than 4000000. It is asking for the sum of all even F(n) less than 4000000.

Think about the sum of all F(n) where F(n) < 10.

> 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8

I could do this by calculating F(1), then F(2), then F(3), and so on... and then checking they are less than 10 before adding them up.

Or I could store two variables...

```
F1 = 1
F2 = 2
```

And a total...

```
Total = 3
```

Now I can turn this into a while loop and lose the recursion altogether. In fact, the most complex thing I'm doing is adding two numbers together...

I came up with this...

```
func sumEvenFibonacci(lessThan limit: Int) -> Int {
    // store the first two Fibonacci numbers
    var n1 = 1
    var n2 = 2

    // and a cumulative total
    var total = 0

    // repeat until you hit the limit
    while n2 < limit {
        // if the current Fibonacci is even then add to total
        if n2 % 2 == 0 {
            total += n2
        }

        // move the stored Fibonacci numbers up by one.
        let temp = n2
        n2 = n2 + n1
        n1 = temp
    }

    return total
}
```

It runs in a fraction of a second.

```
sumEvenFibonacci(lessThan: 4000000)
```

Finds the correct answer.

In fact this... `sumEvenFibonacci(lessThan: 1000000000000000000)` runs in about half a second.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution seems to be fast(er) although an Int64 will not be sufficient to store the result. The sum of Fibonacci numbers from 2..91 is 7,527,100,471,027,205,936 but the largest number you can store in an Int64 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. For this you need to use some other types like [BigInteger](https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp)

Comment: There is also built-in `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: Also, there is the issue that the question has been interpreted incorrectly by the OP. The question asks for the sum of all Fibonacci numbers not exceeding 4,000,000. It does not ask for the sum of the first 4,000,000 Fibonacci numbers. That results in a very different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the recursive, and it cache in the memory.If you iteration 42, it maybe has so many fibonacci function in your memory, and recursive.So it isn't suitable for recursive, and you can store the result in the array, not the reason of the swift.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer in two different ways

```
func solution2_recursive()
{
    func fibonacci(number: Int) -> (Int)
    {
        if number <= 1
        {
            return number
        }
        else
        {
            return fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2)
        }
    }
    var sum = 0
    print("calculating...")
    for index in 2..<50
    {
        print (index)
        let f = fibonacci(index)

        if( f < 4000000)
        {
            if (f % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum += f
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(sum)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

solution 2

```
func solution2()
{
    var phiOne : Double = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0
    var phiTwo : Double = (1.0 - sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0

    func findFibonacciNumber (nthNumber : Double) -> Int64
    {
        let nthNumber : Double = (pow(phiOne, nthNumber) - (pow(phiTwo, nthNumber))) / sqrt(5.0)
        return Int64(nthNumber)
    }

    var sum : Int64 = 0

    print("calculating...")
    for index in 2..<50
    {
        let f = findFibonacciNumber(Double(index))
        if(f < 4000000)
        {
            if (f % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum += f
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(sum)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put the solution in your answer. Project Euler is better when people can't go and google the solution. Keep the code. It might be useful but remove the solution.