# Analyzing an algorithm with recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + c?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I know that this type of equations can be solved by many methods, but I want to use to use recurrence tree method to solve the equation.Can anyone show me how it is done by recurrence tree method?

Comment: You should try first, then we can help you fix it

Comment: isT(n) guaranteed to be non-negative ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Is there an anchor? Like `T(0)=0` and `T(1)=0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Answer (score 3):

Recursion trees are used to draw out the execution of a recursive algorithm. This recurrence you're describing is basically the same recurrence as the recursive Fibonacci algorithm, where this equation:

```
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

is solved for recursively, using an algorithm like this:

```
int fib(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x == 1)
        return 1;

    return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2); //Does this recurrence look familiar?
}
```

Which produces this tree for input 5:

```
                    5
                   / \
                  /   \
                 /     \ 
                /       \     
               /         \
              /           \
             /             \
            4               3
           / \             / \
          /   \           /   1
         /     \         2
        3       2       / \
       / \     / \     1   0
      /   \   /   \  
     2     1 1     0
    / \
   /   \
  1     0
```

Above, I have drawn a very simple recurrence tree for the Fibonacci sequence. I simply plugged in the first number (5) and continued to produce a simple tree from it's subsequent recursive calls. You can see that the height of the tree is N and the branching factor is 2, so our upper bound must be O(2^n). You can generalize this to get the answer to your specific question and any other recurrences you want to find using this method.