# What is the Big O complexity of this program...I got O(2^n) but i am not able to find correct answer

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

n = int(input())
for val in range(n):
    print(fib(val))
```

#I did some calculation and got O(n^2)but I dont know the correct answer

Comment: What do you think it is? Show us your analysis.

Comment: This seems clearly an assignment or an exercise of a programming course that you are supposed to complete, and you are not showing that at least you give a try to figure it out.

Comment: This is not a site for getting people to do your homework for you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: I got O(2^n) but my friends are arguing that it is O(N*2^n). I did calculation on my own if u want I will send u @n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different argument:

Your algorithm recurses until it "bottoms out" at `fib(1)` which returns 1.

So you are getting the fibonacci number by doing (fibonacci number) calls and adding the 1s.

So `fib(n)` is `O(fib(n))`.

Binet's Fibonacci formula can be written as `fib(n) == int(0.5 + (phi ** n) / (5 ** 0.5))` where phi is the Golden Ratio, 1.6180339...

Stripping constants, you get `O(phi ** n)` which reduces to `O(2 ** n)`.

Now, `fib(n)` is actually a bit more than `O(fib(n))`, because you also make a bunch of calls to `fib(0)` which returns 0 - thus it adds to the number of calls but not the sum.

It turns out that when computing `fib(n)`, you make `fib(n - 1)` calls to `fib(0)` (**challenge: write a function to prove this!**).

So `fib(n)` is actually `O(fib(n) + fib(n - 1))` which is `O(fib(n + 1))` which is `O(phi ** (n + 1))`, which still reduces to `O(2 ** n)`.

Comment: If you think your answer differs somehow from the answers in the duplicate, write it there.

Comment: I got the same but I am not able to convince everyone around me