# How do we calculate number of calls in naive fibonaci?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, time-complexity, exponential

So the following is not optimized fibonacci function:

```
sub fib {  
    my ( $n ) = @_;  
    return 1 if( $n == 1 || $n == 2 );  
    return fib( $n - 1 ) + fib( $n - 2 );  
}
```

I actually printed the number of times `fib(3)` was called when we try to find the fibonacci of 20.
It is 2584. `fib(2)` is called 4181.
As far as I know this algorithm shows exponential behavior.
My question is how could I calculate that `fib(3)` would have been called 2584 times **without** actually keeping a counter in the code and printing the function calls? How is the exponential part calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fib(i)` gets called directly only from `fib(i+1)` and `fib(i+2)`, and once for each call.

Thus `calls(i)` (number of calls of `fib(i)`) equals `calls(i+1) + calls(i+2)`

So if we start at `m` and we try to calculate `calls(n)`, we have the following:

```
calls(m)   = 1             (= fib(1))
calls(m-1) = 1             (= fib(2))
calls(m-2) = 2 (1+1)       (= fib(3))
calls(m-3) = 3 (1+2)       (= fib(4))
calls(m-4) = 5 (2+3)       (= fib(5))
...
```

This is just the Fibonacci sequence where we want to calculate the `m-n+1`-th number
(to see why it's exactly `m-n+1`, consider when `n = m`, which should be `fib(1)`).

```
calls(n) = fib(m-n+1)
```

We can use an optimised Fibonacci function here to efficiently (in linear time) calculate `fib(m-n+1)`, which will be the number of calls of `fib(n)` there will be in the unoptimised version.

---

For your example, `fib(3)` gets called `2584` times if you call `fib(20)`.
`fib(20-3+1) = fib(18) = 2584`.

---

Note: `calls(1) = calls(3)` (since `fib(2)` doesn't call `fib(1)`), so that's a special case.

Comment: I do not understand the answer. `fib(18)` is called 2 times only. I have all the calls printed.

Comment: If you call fib(18) directly (e.g. `print fib(18)` or whatever), the result that's returned (not the number of calls) is 2584.

Comment: The complexity of this function is `T(N)=T(N-1) + T(N-2)` which is called as exponential. My question is how do we prove the exponential part so as to be able to calculate that `fib(3)` would be called 2584 times? Saying that `fib(3)` will be called `fib(18)` times does not show me some exponential calculation. This is the part I am confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question - [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence), [Exponential lower bound for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571433/exponential-lower-bound-for-fibonacci-numbers)?

Comment: So I went through the answers. The `fib(n)` is approximated by `e^n`. But the answers are about the steps required to calculated `fib(n)` which is almost `e^n`. They don't say (or I missed the point) for any n e.g. `fib(30)` how do we calculate how many times `fib(3)` is called. Somehow your answer gives a hint that it can be found by `fib(18)` but I didn't really get fully the intuition

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the Fibbonaci number at `Target - desired number + 1` so in the case of asking what is the number of times `fib(3)` is called in `fib(20)` it would be the value of `fib(20 - 3 + 1)` (which is `fib(18) = 2584`).

If you draw out a tree representing the fibbonaci calls you can see this for yourself!

Comment: How do you intuitively prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Dukeling is showing you the sequence that leads to how many times `fib(3)` is called: `fib(20) (m)` gets called once, `fib(19) (m-1)` once, then `fib(18)` gets called each time `fib(19)` or `fib(20)` are called which totals 1+1.

As we move down the sequence on the way to finding how many times `fib(3)` is called, you'll notice that the numbers (and calculation) correspond with the Fibonacci sequence itself. We go from 20 down to 3 so m - n + 1 steps, and each step corresponds with the next Fibonacci number. By the time we reach how many times `fib(3)` (fib(n)) is called, the sequence has come to the `m-n+1`th Fibonacci number, which corresponds with how many times `f(n)` is called during the unoptimised recursion.