# Stuck on a simple fibonacci with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't seem to understand the output of this block of code:

```
function fib(x) {
  return (x === 0 || x === 1) ? x : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
}

fib(7);
// output is 13
```

Here's my thinking process:

- Pass int to the function and check if it's 0 or 1
- If it's 0 or 1, proceed to return the passed value
- If it's not 0 or 1, minus 1 from 7, then minus 2 from 7
- Return the output which according through my (obviosly faulty) thinking would be 11

How does the function come to the result of 13?

Comment: You should learn about `recursion` that's what happening here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion

Comment: The function is unnecessarily hard to read. Would you appreciate a re-written form that's more readable?

Comment: @glhrmv Sorry, but how is this hard to read? It's a simple ternary operator.

Comment: Well it's easier to step through how something is working if it's on multiple lines, as opposed to jumbled up into one. Good luck using the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement with this.

Comment: That's pretty simple recursion here. If `x` is 0 or 1 you return `x` or you return the sum of results of same function called twice by one and two less values of `x`. Of course you have to keep in mind that a function returns to where it was called from and code execution continues from that point on.

Comment: according to your function fib(7) = fib(6) + fib(5) if you put the values in there its fib(7) = 8 + 5 = 13 , how did you find 11 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't understand this Fibonacci program flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273748/cant-understand-this-program-flow) (this question was originally about C#, but the core general understanding problem and answer seem to be the same to me)

Comment: @ÖmerErden 6 + 5 = 11, just missing the recursive call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Step  | Function | Result                                 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1    | f(7)     | f(6) + f(5) = a
|  2    |   a      | [f(5)+f(4)] + [f(4)+f(3)] = b
|  3    |   b      | [ [f(4)+f(3)] + [f(3)+f(2)] ] + [ [(f(3)+f(2)] + [f(2)+f(1)] ] = c
|  4    |   c      | [ [ [f(3)+f(2)] + [f(2)+f(1)] ] + [ [f(2)+f(1)] + [f(1) + f(0)] ] ] + [ [ [f(2)+f(1)]  + [f(1) + f(0)] ] + [ [f(1) + f(0)] + 1] ] = d
|  5    |   d      | [ [ [ [f(2)+f(1)]  + [f(1) + f(0)] ] + [ [f(1) + f(0)] +1] ] + [ [ [f(1) + f(0)] +1] + [1 + 0] ] ] + [ [ [ [f(1) + f(0)] +1]  + [1 + 0] ] + [ [1 + 0] + 1] ] = e
|  6    |   e      | [ [ [ [ [f(1) + f(0)] +1]  + [1 + 0] ] + [ [1 + 0] +1] ] + [ [ [1+ 0] +1] + [1 + 0] ] ] + [ [ [ [1 + 0] +1]  + [1 + 0] ] + [ [1 + 0] + 1] ] = f
|  7    |   f      | [ [ [ [ [1 + 0] +1]  + [1 + 0] ] + [ [1 + 0] +1] ] + [ [ [1+ 0] +1] + [1 + 0] ] ] + [ [ [ [1 + 0] +1]  + [1 + 0] ] + [ [1 + 0] + 1] ] = g

g= 13
```

Answer (score 3):

**`If it's not 0 or 1, minus 1 from 7, then minus 2 from 7`** Here is the fault. It will recurse, stacks will be built up (Meaning more `fib()` functions will be called). If you would like a pen and paper solution, here it is. Everything is done from left to right, mind that. I have shown a simple example for `x=4`. Try extending it for `x=7`. Will make the concept of `recursion` clearer to you!!

[image: Fibonacci Recursion]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the beautifull world of recursion. It may be a hard concept to grasp, but very rewarding when you finally understand it.

@Elif A have written a nice table which shows exactly how the program run. However, when I learned recursion myself, I had this strategy where I "mapped" all the inputs on a piece of paper, starting with the inputs which gave me a value, instead of a function call. Then I build my way up. I really recommend this strategy, if you have a hard time understanding recursion.

Consider the following code

```
function factorial(n) {
      if (n == 1) {
             return 1;
       }
       else {
             return n*factorial(n-1)
       }
}
```

Lets say we want to find `factorial(5)`. Instead of starting from the top, evaluating `factorial(5)`, lets start at the bottom, building our way up to `factorial(5)`. You'll see why this is a good intuitive way of understanding recursion.

`factorial(1) = 1`

`factorial(2) = 2 * factorial(1) = 2 * 1 = 2`

`factorial(3) = 3 * factorial(2) = 2 * 3 = 6`

`factorial(4) = 4 * factorial(3) = 4 * 6 = 24`

`factorial(5) = 5 * factorial(4) = 5 * 24 = 120`

Again, let me precise that this is just a way of understanding recursion. The table, which I mentioned is how the program actually run, and do the recursion.

Comment: Let's hope the OP has ES2015+. Otherwise, their JavaScript won't do tail call optimization, so that code's going to get rather inefficient for large args...

Comment: Just of pure curiosity, what is tail call optimization?

Comment: [What is tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)

Comment: @PM2Ring Even in engines that support TCO, this wouldn't apply.

Comment: I don't understand. All I tried was to simplify what recursion is. I need to read up on TCO, because I am not on the same page as you.

Comment: @PM2Ring: The tail "call" is to `*`, not to `factorial`, so I don't get your point?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Huh? IME, a tail call optimizer would optimize the recursive call to factorial in Markus's code. But I was actually talking about the OP's recursive Fibonacci code. I think you'd agree that without TCO or caching that a doubly recursive Fibonacci function gets pretty bad unless the arg is small. Try fib(30)...

Comment: @PM2Ring: A tail call optimizer will optimize the tail call. The tail call is (roughly) "the last call". `factorial` is not the last call, `*` is executed afterwards. The tail call is to `*`, not to `factorial`.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot that what is returned if **fib**(6)+**fib**(5), not 6+5

This schema can help you understand the logic and order of calculations for `fib(5)` :

[image: recursive Fibonacci function for fib(5)]

Try to draw the same diagram for fib(6), and then for fib(7), and you will understand recursion much better.

*And also quickly conclude that this is a terribly inefficient algorithm to use if your goal is actually calculating Fibonacci numbers*

(taken and modified image from [an other answer of mine on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273997/479251), diagram originally from http://composingprograms.com/pages/28-efficiency.html)