# Fibonacci sequence time and space complexity

Tags: python, big-o

This is not the most efficient way to get Fibonacci sequence numbers but I am learning Big O and would like confirmation and explanation of the space and time efficiency of the code below. The code is in Python and I wrote it such that I use a list and append to it and just return the last value.

The append method takes O(1) time as shown [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) but I am doing the operation almost n times so would I get O(n) for time complexity?

With regard to space complexity, should I consider the space used as an [arithmetic series](http://www.mathwords.com/a/arithmetic_series.htm) because the list would have to be moved elsewhere if the number entered is larger than what is given to the function stack at the beginning?

The code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence) is for the recursive approach.

```
def getFib(position):
  if position == 0:
    return 0
  if position == 1:
    return 1

  list_ = [0, 1]
  previous = 1

  for pos in range(2, position+1):
    list_.append(list_[pos-1] + list_[pos-2])

  return list_[position]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(getFib(0))
  print(getFib(1))
  print(getFib(2))
  print(getFib(3))
  print(getFib(4))
  print(getFib(5))
  print(getFib(6))
  print(getFib(7))
  print(getFib(8))
  print(getFib(9))
```

Comment: This is O(n) Time and Space Complexity? You are doing a `for` loop from `0 to n`. Each time a new item is added.

Comment: You have a loop that takes `position` steps and create a list of size `position`. Seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time complexity: `O(n)` because you are executing `n` times your loop that has a constant time complexity.

space complexity: `O(n)` because you are storing `n` numbers in your list.

Of course, you didn't need to store all the numbers but only the last two values. That would have reduced the space complexity to `O(1)`.

Comment: Is it O(n) because you are considered amortized analysis as shown here where O(3n) simplifies to O(n)? https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/dynamic-array-amortized-analysis

Comment: Yes, I used as assumption that `append` is constant in time (O(1)).