# Why is one of these two algorithms for finding the n-th Fibonacci number more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci

When calculating the 64th Fibonacci number, the first algorithm takes several hours, and the second one takes less than a second.

Why is the efficiency of the second algorithm so much higher than that of the first one?

They look very similar.

```
def fib_divide_recursion(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return n-1
    else:
        return fib_divide_recursion(n-1) + fib_divide_recursion(n-2)

def fib_linear_recursion(n, prev={}):
    if n <= 2:
        return n-1
    try:
        return prev[n]
    except KeyError:
        prev[n] = fib_linear_recursion(n - 1, prev) + 
            fib_linear_recursion(n - 2, prev)
        return prev[n]
```

Comment: Because the first one does more work. Count the number of function calls it performs.

Comment: Evaluating `fib_divide_recursion(25)` calls the function 150049 times, evaluating `fib_linear_recursion(25)` calls it 47 times, and the difference gets worse quickly as `n` grows.

Comment: Except of that, because you are using recursion for the most common example of iterative programming.

Comment: @Klaus Yeah, but it can be valuable to learn Fibonacci recursively, too - in fact, it's one of the most common intro-to-recursion programs.

Comment: And it is the most wrong example for teaching programming.

Comment: @Klaus Well, I agree with you there, but unfortunately it's hard to counteract the tidal wave of precedent. Anyway, learning Fibonacci is useful for understanding the pros and cons of recursion vs. iteration, even if it's not ideal, simply because it's ridiculously well-established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second implementation is using "memoizing" to remember previously calculated Fibonacci values.

Consider that you're trying to calculate `fib(5)`: You first have to calculate `fib(4)` and `fib(3)`. `fib(4)` itself also requires you to calculate `fib(3)`. In fact, for every Fibonacci number, you can either calculate each of the preceding Fibonacci numbers once and store them (this is the memoization method). Or, at much worse performance, you can recalculate each Fibonacci number that you need, even if you've already calculated it before. Clearly, without memoization, you will need to do exponentially more work, and for high Fibonacci numbers, this really makes a difference, as you've observed.

Comment: thanks, and why can't I use prev=[] replace prev{}, even I change KeyError to IndexError too

Comment: @longchaos Really, that's a different question which you should post separately if you want it properly answered. But the short answer is that a list is not a dictionary: You can't index into a part of the list that doesn't exist yet and expect it to be automatically created. You would have to initialise it with the number of elements you're going to need, which would not be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the first algorithm is O(2^n).

The second one caches the results in `prev`, so it never computes `fib_linear_recursion` more than once for a given number. Its complexity is linear, O(n).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/6352677) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

1st algorithm is using only recursion while 2nd algorithm is using Dynamic Programming i.e Recursion with memoization.

If you draw a tree for 1st algorithm you'll see repeated nodes. But with 2nd algorithm it is storing the already calculated node so program don't have to calculate for that again and again