# Recursion in Common Lisp, pushing values, and the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, fibonacci, clisp

This is ***not*** a homework assignment. In the following code:

```
(defparameter nums '())

(defun fib (number)
  (if (< number 2)
      number
    (push (+ (fib (- number 1)) (fib (- number 2))) nums))
  return nums)

(format t "~a " (fib 100))
```

Since I am quite inexperienced with Common Lisp, I am at a loss as to why the function does not return an value. I am a trying to print first 'n' values, e.g., 100, of the Fibonacci Sequence.

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you getting an error complaining that the variable `return` doesn't exist?

Comment: It stated that the value was empty. I have since changed the function to return only the nth value, via 'return-from fib', and it works as expected.

Comment: @CaitlinG Even after removing the offending `return`, your function will fail, because in the embedded call, the number will wind down to less than 2, whereupon `nums` will be returned, which will still contains `nil`, which is not a number, which will generate an error.

Comment: While you can find perfect answer already below you may find [this](https://www.cliki.net/Fibonacci) overview of different ways to implement Fibonacci numbers interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function unconditionally returns `nums` (but only if a variable called `return` exists). To see why, we can format it like this:

```
(defun fib (number)
  (if (< number 2)
    number
    (push (+ (fib (- number 1)) (fib (- number 2))) nums))
  return 
  nums)
```

If the `number` is less than `2`, then it evaluates the expression `number`, uselessly, and throws away the result. Otherwise, it pushes the result of the `(+ ....)` expression onto the `nums` list.  Then it uselessly evaluates `return`, throwing away the result. If a variable called `return` doesn't exist, that's an error situation. Otherwise, it evaluates `nums` and that is the return value.

In Common Lisp, there is a `return` operator for terminating and returning out of anonymous named blocks (blocks whose name is the symbol `nil`). If you define a named function with `defun`, then an invisible block exists which is not anonymous: it has the same name as that function. In that case, `return-from` can be used:

```
(defun function ()
  (return-from function 42) ;; function terminates, returns 42
  (print 'notreached))     ;; this never executes
```

Certain standard control flow and looping constructs establish a hidden anonymous block, so `return` can be used:

```
 (dolist (x '(1 2 3))
   (return 42))            ;; loop terminates, yields 42 as its result
```

If we use `(return ...)` but there is no enclosing anonymous block, that is an error.

The expression `(return ...)` is different from just `return`, which evaluates a variable named by the symbol `return`, retrieving its contents.

It is not clear how to repair your `fib` function, because the requirements are unknown. The side effect of pushing values into a global list normally doesn't belong inside a mathematical function like this, which should be pure (side-effect-free).

Answer (score 8):

An obvious approach to computing fibonacci numbers is this:

```
(defun fib (n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))

(defun fibs (n)
  (loop for i from 1 below n
        collect (fib i)))
```

A little thought should tell you why no approach like this is going to help you compute the first 100 Fibonacci numbers: the time taken to compute `(fib n)` is equal to or a little more than the time taken to compute `(fib (- n 1))` plus the time taken to compute `(fib (- n 2))`: this is exponential (see [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence#360773)).

A good solution to this is *memoization*: the calculation of `(fib n)` repeats subcalculations a huge number of times, and if we can just remember the answer we computed last time we can avoid doing so again.

(An earlier version of this answer has an overcomplex macro here: something like that may be useful in general but is not needed here.)

Here is how you can memoize `fib`:

```
(defun fib (n)
  (check-type n (integer 0) "natural number")
  (let ((so-far '((2 . 1) (1 . 1) (0 . 0))))
    (labels ((fibber (m)
               (when (> m (car (first so-far)))
                 (push (cons m (+ (fibber (- m 1))
                                  (fibber (- m 2))))
                       so-far))
               (cdr (assoc m so-far))))
      (fibber n))))
```

This keeps a table – an alist – of the results it has computed so far, and uses this to avoid recomputation.

With this memoized version of the function:

```
> (time (fib 1000))
Timing the evaluation of (fib 1000)

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.000
Allocation   = 101944 bytes
0 Page faults
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
```

The above definition uses a fresh cache for each call to `fib`: this is fine, because the local function, `fibber` does reuse the cache.  But you can do better than this by putting the cache outside the function altogether:

```
(defmacro define-function (name expression)
  ;; Install EXPRESSION as the function value of NAME, returning NAME
  ;; This is just to avoid having to say `(setf ...)`: it should
  ;; probably do something at compile-time too so the compiler knows
  ;; the function will be defined.
  `(progn
     (setf (fdefinition ',name) ,expression)
     ',name))

(define-function fib
  (let ((so-far '((2 . 1) (1 . 1) (0 . 0))))
    (lambda (n)
      (block fib
        (check-type n (integer 0) "natural number")
        (labels ((fibber (m)
                   (when (> m (car (first so-far)))
                     (push (cons m (+ (fibber (- m 1))
                                      (fibber (- m 2))))
                           so-far))
                   (cdr (assoc m so-far))))
          (fibber n))))))
```

This version of `fib` will share its cache between calls, which means it is a little faster, allocates a little less memory but may be less thread-safe:

```
> (time (fib 1000))
[...]
Allocation   = 96072 bytes
[...]

> (time (fib 1000))
[...]
Allocation   = 0 bytes
[...]
```

Interestingly memoization was invented (or at least named) by Donald Michie, who worked on breaking Tunny (and hence with Colossus), and who I also knew slightly: the history of computing is still pretty short!

---

Note that memoization is one of the times where you can end up fighting a battle with the compiler.  In particular for a function like this:

```
(defun f (...)
  ...
  ;; no function bindings or notinline declarations of F here
  ...
  (f ...)
  ...)
```

Then the compiler is allowed (but not required) to assume that the apparently recursive call to `f` is a recursive call into the function it is compiling, and thus to avoid a lot of the overhead of a full function call.  In particular it is not required to retrieve the current function value of the symbol `f`: it can just call directly into the function itself.

What this means is that an attempt to write a *function*, `memoize` which can be used to mamoize an existing recursive function, as `(setf (fdefinition 'f) (memoize #'f))` may not work: the function `f` still call directly into the unmemoized version of itself and won't notice that the function value of `f` has been changed.

This is in fact true even if the recursion is indirect in many cases: the compiler is allowed to assume that calls to a function `g` for which there is a definition in the same file are calls to the version defined in the file, and again avoid the overhead of a full call.

The way to deal with this is to add suitable `notinline` declarations: if a call is covered by a `notinline` declaration (which must be known to the compiler) then it must be made as a full call.  From the [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_inline.htm):

> A compiler is not free to ignore this declaration; calls to the specified functions must be implemented as out-of-line subroutine calls.

What this means is that, in order to memoize functions you have to add suitable `notinline` declarations for recursive calls, and this means that memoizing either needs to be done by a macro, or must rely on the user adding suitable declarations to the functions to be memoized.

This is only a problem because the CL compiler is allowed to be smart: almost always that's a *good* thing!

Answer (score 3):

So you might know that if you know the two previous numbers you can compute the next. What comes after `3,  5`? If you guess `8` you have understood it. Now if you start with `0, 1` and roll `1, 1`, `1, 2`, etc you collect the first variable until you have the number of numbers you'd like:

```
(defun fibs (elements)
  "makes a list of elements fibonacci numbers starting with the first"
  (loop :for a := 0 :then b
        :for b := 1 :then c
        :for c := (+ a b)
        :for n :below elements
        :collect a))

(fibs 10)
; ==> (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Every form in Common Lisp "returns" a value. You can say it evaluates to. eg.

```
(if (< a b)
    5
    10)
```

This evaluates either to `5` or `10`. Thus you can do this and expect that it evaluates to either `15` or `20`:

```
(+ 10 
   (if (< a b)
       5
       10))
```

You basically want your functions to have **one** expression that calculates the result. eg.

```
(defun fib (n)
  (if (zerop n)
      n
      (+ (fib (1- n)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

This evaluates to the result og the `if` expression... `loop` with `:collect` returns the list. You also have `(return expression)` and `(return-from name expression)` but they are usually unnecessary.

Comment: comupe -> compute?

Answer (score 1):

Your global variable `num` is actually not that a bad idea.

It is about to have a central memory about which fibonacci numbers were already calculated. And not to calculate those already calculated numbers again.

This is the very idea of memoization.

But first, I do it in bad manner with a global variable.

### Bad version with global variable `*fibonacci*`

```
(defparameter *fibonacci* '(1 1))

(defun fib (number)
  (let ((len (length *fibonacci*)))
    (if (> len number)
        (elt *fibonacci* (- len number 1)) ;; already in *fibonacci*
        (labels ((add-fibs (n-times)
                   (push (+ (car *fibonacci*)
                            (cadr *fibonacci*))
                         *fibonacci*)
                   (cond ((zerop n-times) (car *fibonacci*))
                         (t (add-fibs (1- n-times))))))
          (add-fibs (- number len))))))

;;> (fib 10)
;;  89
;;> *fibonacci*
;;  (89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1)
```

### Good functional version (memoization)

In memoization, you hide the global `*fibonacci*` variable
into the environment of a lexical function (the memoized version of a function).

```
(defun memoize (fn)
  (let ((cache (make-hash-table :test #'equal)))
    #'(lambda (&rest args)
        (multiple-value-bind (val win) (gethash args cache)
          (if win
              val
              (setf (gethash args cache)
                    (apply fn args)))))))

(defun fib (num)
  (cond ((zerop num) 1)
        ((= 1 num) 1)
        (t (+ (fib (- num 1))
              (fib (- num 2))))))
```

The previously global variable `*fibonacci*` is here actually the local variable `cache` of the `memoize` function - encapsulated/hidden from the global environment,
accessible/look-up-able only through the function `fibm`.

**Applying memoization on `fib` (bad version!)**

```
(defparameter fibm (memoize #'fib))
```

Since common lisp is a Lisp 2 (separated namespace between function and variable names) but we have here to assign the memoized function to a variable,
we have to use `(funcall <variable-name-bearing-function> <args for memoized function>)`.

```
(funcall fibm 10) ;; 89
```

Or we define an additional

```
(defun fibm (num)
  (funcall fibm num))
```

and can do

```
(fibm 10)
```

- However, this saves/memoizes only the out calls e.g. here only the
  Fibonacci value for 10. Although for that, Fibonacci numbers 
  for 9, 8, ..., 1 are calculated, too.
  To make them saved, look the next section!

**Applying memoization on `fib` (better version by @Sylwester - thank you!)**

```
(setf (symbol-function 'fib) (memoize #'fib))
```

Now the original `fib` function is the memoized function,
so all fib-calls will be memoized.
In addition, you don't need `funcall` to call the memoized version,
but just do

```
(fib 10)
```

Comment: `(when (< number 2) 1)` is dead code. even if it hits the rest of the function determins the returned result.

Comment: @Sylwester Thank you! I forgot to delete - in a previous version it was necessay but then I made `*fibonacci*` `'(1 1)`so that this check became unnecessary.

Comment: Also there is a problem with your memoization. You only memoize the outer call. eg. `(fibm 10)` will just save `10` while `fib` is called more than `89` times. It's better to get the function to call it's memoized version in recursive step. eg. `(setf (symbol-function fib) (memoize #'fib))` would make it faster and O(n) worst case.

Comment: @Sylwester Absolutely true! Your comments are always appreciated! Always so smart solutions!

Comment: @Sylwester one has to quote: `(symbol-function 'fib)` - and I added your suggestion! Thanks! - interestingly, `symbol-function` prints also the code of `fib`. I was once asking myself whether there is such kind of reflection.

Comment: Note that you `memoize` is quite hard to write in CL, and in particular your version may not work: this is because within `fib` the compiler is allowed to assume that calls to `fib` are to the same function, unless it is declared `notinline`.  So a correct memoizer for CL needs to insert suitable `notinline` declarations & hence be a macro.

Comment: About getting the source. The best way is to use [function-lambda-expression](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fn_lam.htm), but as you see there is no requirement to keep the source once compiled so `nil` is a valid return, but it's better than trying to parse the output of `#'fib`

Comment: @tfb What you mean exactly? that way that @Sylwester suggested was correct. It makes also the recursive calls be memoized. I tested it with the `time` function - and after memoization, the calls get at least 1 magnitude faster.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: the calls got faster *in your implementation, with whatever compiler options you have set*.  Other implementations, or other compiler settings for your implementation may make this not true.  Clozure CL s a good example of an implementation where it is not true (with the default compilation settings).  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @tfb thank you! Now understood a little. - To date I am using sbcl or clisp but not with other implementations. Well, things get much more complex if one wants to write sth suitable for all implementations ... Thank you for the hint! ;)