# Explanation to time complexity of Fib(n)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I very well know that recursive Fib(n) has time complexity of O(2^n). I am also able to come to that result by solving the following

```
T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2).
```

But when I take an example I get stuck. For eg: n=4
acc to recursive solution

```
T(1) = u #some constant 
and, T(2) = u #some constant
Now, T(4) = T(3)+T(2)
          = T(2)+T(1)+u
          = u+u+u 
          = 3u
```

I was expecting the result to be 16u.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/7629560

Comment: Fib(n) is O(2^n), but it's not Theta(2^n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computational complexity of Fibonacci Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: @PaulHankin I had read that answer and understood the calculations as well, but got stuck when I tried those calculations with a particular example as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Big-O notation is related to the asymptotic complexity, so we are interested in how the complexity grows for big numbers.

Big-O refers actually to an upper limit for the growth of a function. Formally, `O(g)` is a set of functions that are growing not faster than `k*g`.

Let me give you a few examples of functions that are in `O(2^n)`:

- 2^n
- 2^n - 1000000000000n
- 2^n - 100
- 2^n + 1.5^n + n^100

The fact that `T(n) in O(2^n)` doesn't mean, that the number of operations will be exactly `2^n`.

It only means, that the limit of the supremum of a sequence `|T(n)/(2^n)|` as `n -> inf` is finite.

Comment: But if it's negative infinity then the complexity is not optimal :)

Comment: @samthegolden oh yea!

Comment: The definition is wrong; the "limit" form of the definition of big O is that lim sup |f/g| is finite as n -> inf. The lim sup is necessary because often the limit doesn't exist. The absolute value in the definition prevents any idea of minus infinity coming in.

Comment: I can see you've edited it, but you still have a wrong definition. T(n) in O(2^n) means that lim sup |T/2^n| is finite. It doesn't mean that the limit of |T/2^n| exists (although it does in this case because 2^n grows exponentially faster than T, and the limit is zero).

Comment: You've edited it again, but it's still wrong. It's the lim sup that is finite, not the limit. They're not the same thing. Here's wikipedia's definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: @PaulHankin now it should be fine