# is the following way correct for determines the complexity of Fibonacci function?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory, fibonacci, analysis

i would like to know if the following explanation is already correct in order to determine the complexity of Fibonacci function ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptgA7.png)

Comment: Create a recurrence relation that reflects the number of operations to be made and solve it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Please include the gist of your posts in the posts themselves. Follow prompts like `enter image description here`. Check the embedding of the pixel raster - and if that is a rendering of text, better include said text in your question. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)