# c# Fibonacci number 80

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fibonacci, factorial

Why my code doesnot works for number 50 or higher? for factorial it works but not for fibonacci.
it seems that it calculates something but always black console there

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Training_Project
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fib(50));
            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(100));
        }
      
        static BigInteger Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return n * Factorial(n - 1);
        }
        static BigInteger Fib(int n) 
        {
            if (n <= 2)
                return 1;

            return Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Think about how many function calls you're making to calculate the output.

Comment: Computational complexity .This might be your answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360773/11573849)

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Does the answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cache already calculated Fibonacci numbers, you save yourself some trouble (ref. Saleh Ahmadi's comment to your post).

You could e.g. add a `Dictionary` to your class to keep track of what you have already calculated

```csharp
static Dictionary<int, BigInteger> _fibonacciOfNumber = new();
```

, and lookup values from there when they exist:

```csharp
static BigInteger Fib(int n) 
{
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!_fibonacciOfNumber.ContainsKey(n))
    {
        _fibonacciOfNumber[n] = Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2);
    }

    return _fibonacciOfNumber[n];
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmjoud).

---

With caching, calculating the fibonacci number for e.g. `30` requires **57** calls to `Fib()`; whereas **1.664.079** calls to `Fib()` are required without caching.

To see a comparison between how many times `Fib( )` is called for each of the two different approaches, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CdA7l9).