# Recursion in bash(fibonacci sequence)

Tags: bash, recursion, fibonacci

The main problem my code doesn't do echo every time(fibonacci sequence)

```
#!/bin/bash

function fib(){
        if [ $1 -le 0 ]; then
                echo 0
        elif [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
                echo 1
        else
                echo $[`fib $[$1 - 2]` + `fib $[$1 - 1]` ]
        fi
}

fib $1
```

i was expecting it will do echo every time. It shows:

```
~/Bash$ ./fn.sh 12
144
```

but i need it to show like this:

```
~/Bash$ ./fn.sh 12
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

Comment: See [Trying to call a function within a function in Bash but it returns errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72228033/4154375).

Answer (score 1):

Your function is consuming the output of its invocation via backticks (command substitution). Only the last output is sent to the terminal. Your function will only return the n-th number of the Fibonacci sequence.

If you want to return all the numbers of the sequence up to a certain point, you can use a loop:

```
for i in $(seq "$i"); do
  fib "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method might be:

```
#!/bin/bash

fibseq () {
    echo "$1"
    if (($3 > 0)); then fibseq "$2" $(($1 + $2)) $(($3 - 1)); fi
}

if (($1 > 0)); then fibseq 0 1 "$1"; fi
```

Note that this is just a loop disguised as recursion. This method is much more efficient than the naive recursive version to compute Fibonacci sequences. Arguments to `fibseq` function: `$3` serves as a counter, `$1` and `$2` are the last two Fibonacci numbers.
As an aside note, you can replace the `$(($1 + $2))` with `$(bc <<< "$1 + $2")` if you want arbitrary-precision arithmetic.
Finally, don't use the `$[…]` form for arithmetic expansion. Use `$((…))` instead.

Comment: Useful, but OP probably wants to know why their code didn't work.